# Does exit($status) violate the single responsibility principle?

Tags: php

The [the PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) about the exit construct states:

> exit — Output a message and terminate the current script

Based on that, would it be correct to think that it violates [the single responsibility principle](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes.  However the exact violation isn't *that* bad...  The Single Responsibility Principle is actually an abstract principle that can be applied to any unit of code.  In [Steve McConnell's *Code Complete 2*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670), he actually talks about this as *cohesion*.  In practice, this is a more specific form of the single-responsibility-principle used for routines.

The most desirable kind of cohesion according to him is *functional cohesion* where a routine performs one and only one operation (the examples he shows are `sin()`, `getCustomerName()`, `eraseFile()`, etc).  So, `exit()` does 2 things.  Therefore it shows *Temporal cohesion* (the operations are done in the same routine because they are done at the same time).

Now, the original arguments to `exit($arg)` was the return status of the applicaiton (See: [linux exit status codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)).  In C, this is the integer value returned from `main()`.  But since PHP doesn't have a native function, it was added in to the `exit()` parameter.  Try it, add `exit(2)`, and the return value of the program will be a status 2 (0 is usually success, see [are there any standard linux exit status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)).

However, since PHP has a low barrier to entry, most developers likely won't know about status codes.  So, it was made to accept a string.  If the argument is a string, the *status* is echoed out on STDOUT, and then the application terminates.  If it's an integer, it'll be returned from the program.  So it's an artifact.

Now, is it a problem?  Not really.  Is it ideal?  No.  But it's also not horrible, since they are related.  In the end, I wouldn't lose sleep over it...

Answer (score 5):

No, because `exit` is a procedural language construct, not a member function of any class. The single responsibility principle is supposed to apply to object-oriented programming, something which does not encompass the entire basis of the PHP language (only a portion of it).