# Exit status 11: What does it mean?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a PHP CLI script ( http://codepad.org/w6iyLLdv ) which stubbornly returns exit code 11, despite the `exit(0)` and the lack of any apparent problem.

[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Appendix E. Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) lists nothing special about 11, and Google finds nothing about it in general nor specifically related to PHP - except possibly [Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux).

Of course I can check for an exit status of 0 *or* 11 in my calling code, but that's dirty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255218/why-is-it-returning-exit-status-11

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255218/why-is-it-returning-exit-status-11 - sorry, poor communication!  (Mikhail beat me to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally thought to check Apache's error.log, and the 11 status was accompanied by this: PHP Warning: Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I found the solution here: http://www.somacon.com/p520.php Apparently I accidentally put an extra << extension="imagick.so" >> line in php.ini. Removing it allowed the CLI script to return status 0.

Note: After I posted this, I started getting a PHP-Warning from imagick about no permissions to create the  ~/.gnome2 directory, and the 11 status.  So seeing the 0 status after applying this fix may have been a fluke.

Answer (score 0):

Is it exiting with exit code 11, or *signal* 11? If it's the latter, it's crashing with a SIGSEGV.

Otherwise, see if you can figure out which line it is exiting on. For example, insert `exit(0);` after the 10th line, and if it exits with 0 instead of 11 move the exit(0) down a bit. That will at least give us something more to work with.

Comment: It is simply the number placed in the third argument to `exec'; my understanding was that that's the exit status.  By using your advice I was able to confirm that it doesn't exit until that exit(0) in the code.  Placing an exit before that if-block prevented the 11 status.

Comment: Correction: Aapparently I made a mistake in my debugging; the call to flattenImages is the first thing which, if exit(0) comes before it, the 11 status is prevented...  So it's an Image Magick issue.