# C++ application terminates with 143 exit code. What does it mean?

Tags: c++, linux

My C++ application crashes periodically. It writes *Terminated* in the terminal and stops. I don't have any idea what the reason is (GDB is not solution; it is a multithreaded application, and the error appears on a big amount of threads, only that GDB can not process them, due to its low performance).

What does exit code 143 mean on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) Linux? Does it contain information about the reason of the crash?

Comment: Why wouldn't gdb help? It will stop when the crash happens, no matter which thread the crash is in.

Comment: If the Linux kernel killed it, the kernel log (use `dmesg` command) might have some info.

Comment: You could also use e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find pointer problems which can cause crashes. And if you have so many threads that gdb can't copy, you might want to try an lower the number of threads to help find the crash (and besides, having many threads is not always a good idea).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lookup the meaning of exit codes for Linux command line utilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294056/how-to-lookup-the-meaning-of-exit-codes-for-linux-command-line-utilities)

Comment: In order to handle the graceful shutdown of your application you will need to catch the `SIGTERM` signal and trigger the correct shutdown sequence.

Comment: It's the normal behaviour for applications to exit immediately if they don't have the suiting **Signal Handler** implemented.

Comment: There are *plenty* of duplicates for this. A starting point is *[Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)* (2009). See also [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1101957). E.g., from [the highest scored answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux/1535733#1535733), 143 = 128 + 15 = 143 →Fatal error signal "15" (whatever that is)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

143 usually means the application caught a `SIGTERM` signal, meaning the process was killed.  This could be because another process killed it, or perhaps because the operating system killed it for using too much memory or some other resource, etc.  Without more information, it's hard to know.

Answer (score 26):

There are some exit codes which have either defined or generally agreed upon meaning.

In case of 143, which is 128 + 15, that means program died with signal 15, which is SIGTERM

> According to the above table, exit codes 1 - 2, 126 - 165, and 255 have special meanings, and should therefore be avoided for user-specified exit parameters.

See the table at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Answer (score 5):

A shell-faked exit code of the form `128+KillingSignal` means the program was killed by some `KillingSignal`.
Killing signal #15 is `SIGTERM` (Try `kill -l 15`, `kill -l $((143-128))` or even `kill -l 143` (kill knows about this shell convention) to get a written description (TERM in this case) of the signal). `SIGTERM` is the default signal sent by the `kill` utility if no other signal is specified. It's a basic termination request.

Likely, some user or some application killed it (`SIGTERM` is a catchable signal—if the kernel were to kill (out of memory condition or a security violation), it wouldn't be so gentle, sending the-always -uncatchable `SIGKILL` or a special uncatchable `SIGSYS`). Much less likely, the program killed itself with `SIGTERM` and much much less likely, in defiance of conventions, the program exited with the actual value 143.

Answer (score -1):

Error 143 means that the application is been killed by some other application or the OS itself. this error is due to many reasons such as performing some unauthorized operation i.e. exploiting user privileges, or the system cannot provide the required drive or directory ,or problem in DNS configuration, or in rare cases inexact float point result..but without sufficient information exact cause is hard to tell...

Comment: As the others already explained it means that the application has received a **Shutdown Signal**. That does not indicate any error. It is the normal procedure to terminate a process by the operating system or by the parent process.