# Detecting meaning of system() function's return value in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, signals, system, return-value

When I execute a command using `system(COMMAND)` function in `C++` code running on Linux,
the return values of calls of `system(COMMAND)` are not same from each other.
Do we have any ways to detect **segmentation fault** or **abnormal termination** by using return value of `system(COMMAND)` function?

For example, when I got segmentation fault after executing a command by using `system` function, I confirmed the return value of that function was 35584. However, I could not know what that return value means, and I am not sure all possible segmentation faults return 35584.
Is there a way to detect all possible values of return values when I encounter segmentation fault or abnormal termination?

Comment: You could use the lower level `fork`, `pipe`, `dup2`, `close`, `execve`, `waitpid` syscalls. Then `waitpid` gives the right status. You might also use some library specific functions (for example both `Gtk` and `Qt` give functions for asynchronous processes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man 3 system` refers to `man 2 wait` for the meaning of return value. The latter page describes several macros usable with this value, notably `WIFSIGNALED(status)` and `WTERMSIG(status)`. That's what you can use to check for segmentation fault or termination on other signals.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const int result = system("./core_dump"); // core_dump only calls abort()
  std::cout << "result=" << result << '\n';
  std::cout << "Terminated by signal: " << (WIFSIGNALED(result) ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
  std::cout << "Exited normally: " << (WIFEXITED(result) ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output (on Ubuntu 12.10):

```
Aborted (core dumped)
result=34304
Terminated by signal: no
Exited normally: yes
```

It may be surprising that `./core_dump` prints `exited normally: yes`. Although `./core_dump` failed, `system` returns the exit code of the `/bin/sh -c` process running the command, which exited normally.

In contrast, calling `system("/bin/kill -9 $$")` instead of `system("./core_dump")` results in following output:

```
result=9
Terminated by signal: yes
Exited normally: no
```

One further note on the exit code. The `core_dump` example returned the exit code 34304. First, we have to shift it by 8 bits. The result is `35304 >> 8 == 134`, which is the exit code for jobs that were killed with an abort signal. If it failed because of an segfault, we would have gotten 139 instead.

[Here](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/BFROOT/www/Computing/Environment/Tools/Batch/exitcode.html) is a link to a overview of the exit codes.

Finally, here is `core_dump`'s source code that is used for testing:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  abort();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `system` returns the exit code of the `/bin/sh -c` process running the command, and that `sh` don't core dump, even if the program started by the command did.

Answer (score 1):

Linux exit codes are discussed in this question: [Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)

IIRC the return value of system() should correspond to the spawned process' exit code, but that appears to run counter to your observation.  Strange.  I will test.

EDIT:  Observations:

1. I can confirm your return value for system().
2. Note that 35585 == 139 << 8.  139 is the linux exit code for a segfaulted process

Next to check glibc source to get an authoritative answer...

Answer (score 0):

For any arbitrary command? Not really. It's up to each program to give meaning to the exit code. The only thing you can presume is 0 mean success but even that is just convention and not guaranteed either.