# exec Exit Code Meaning for 11

Tags: php, linux, exec, exit-code

I'm using the following code on a linux web server

```
$error = exec('phantomjs table1.js', $op, $code);
echo $code; // prints 11 on screen
```

---

#### table1.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'table1.php';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.render('ss/table1.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

---

#### table1.php

```
echo '<h1>This should be converted to an image</h1>';
```

I went through [***this***](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) link but that code isn't listed there. Any idea what this exit code stands for?

Comment: Is that your complete `table1.js`?

Comment: Yes, that is the complete javascript code. Nothing is above or below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code 11 is a "segmentation fault": A segmentation fault (also segfault) is caused by a program when it tries to allocate data in a piece of memory that is not assigned to the program. It indicates a program error and usually (if not always) crashes the program. In your case, the segfault probably is caused by phantomjs, which indicates perhaps an old or beta version.

Comment: Hmm..that's strange. `table1.js` doesn't have any code outputting `11` in it.

Comment: I just have those two lines listed above in the file (let's call it `abc.php`) When I run `abc.php`, I get `11` shown on screen. Are you referring to what's inside `table1.js`?

Comment: It's a binary file which helps to create screenshots of the page being rendered (In my case, output of `table1.php`). More info [***here***](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: I copied your `table1.js` into mine, and it worked fine (even though nothing gets rendered).

Comment: This exact same code works on my localhost too...the problem is with the production server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28805/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-asprin)

Comment: @BartFriederichs how did you make it work as I am in the same situation now. It works If I run phantom command on server but returns 11 if i run using php exec. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found out.

- Your phantomjs is calling some child process. (My assumption would be you are executing this on node).
- Now, if table1.js exits abruptly, then return code will be binary `00001000` and the main process(node as per assumption) will also exit with the same binary error code.
- Now as per exit status co-relation, both the binaries will be converted to normal sign signals which makes both to be `1` and `1`.

Hence your error code of 11.

Source:
[Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)

Comment: According to that thread, segmentation faults results in the code `11`. I had this segmentation fault listed in my server error log. Any idea why or what the segmentation fault is?

Comment: It is `resource not found`. Check the segmentation fault description [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/segmentation-fault-on-linux-unix.html)

Comment: @asprin If you are trying to save the output of a PHP file, host it on a server and provide a complete URL. I tried out the google image capture script and it worked. So I can say this thing will work. My suggestion is host in on your local and provide a complete path like `http://localhost/table1.php` and then modify your js to fetch from this path.