# Why is no value returned if a function does not explicity use 'ret'

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following program:

```
SECTION .text
main:
     mov ebx, 10
     mov ecx, 50

repeat:
     inc ebx
     loop repeat

     mov eax, ebx
     ret
```

When this program runs, it returns 60 as expected. However, if you drop the final `ret` statement, the program runs fine, but then returns 0. Why is that?

Comment: How do you know it "runs fine"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you leave off the "ret", the computer executes the last "move eax, ebx" and then executes whatever happens to be next in computer memory.

I'm surprised you don't get an illegal instruction/access; that would be the most common response.  Somehow the garbage instruction acts like a return, after trashing the registers.

Its also a little unclear what you mean by "returns 60".  You mean as a value to the command prompt?   It is clear that your program has no defense against illegal instruction traps.
What Windows does when you get such a trap without a defense is unclear to me; I know from experience when I do that Windows tends to just terminate my process and I get some random exit status.   "0" might be such a status.

Try adding:

```
      mov   byte ptr[eax], 0
```

before the "ret" instruction; this will cause an illegal memory reference.  You report what status you get.   It wouldn't suprise me if you got the zero status result in this case.

Comment: The OP clearly got lucky, and whatever function the linker puts right after `main` returns zero.  `main` goes in the code (`.text`) segment, along with the runtime boilerplate startup functions you get from linking with the standard runtime.  I'd expect another function to follow it, rather than data.  Remember this is `main`, not `_start`.

Comment: It's pretty clear he means as the return value from main, the low 8 bits of which end up as the Unix process exit status.  Since you asked, a Unix process that dies with `SIGSEGV` has an exit status of 139.  (Segmentation violation = illegal memory access).  SIGSEGV = signal 11, and 139 = 128+11.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1104641/224132.  Hope this helps explain what the OP was seeing when he let main fall through.

Answer (score 3):

Because it falls through and runs the next function the linker put after it.

See my comments on Ira's answer for why your code didn't just crash.  If you weren't linking with the C runtime library startup code (i.e. you just had `_start` instead of `main`), execution would hit some non-code, and either fault on illegal instruction, or try to access unmapped memory.  See below.

Disassemble your final binary to see what happened.  When I tried this, I found that the linker put `main` between the standard C runtime startup functions `frame_dummy` and `__libc_csu_init`.  It

```
00000000004004f6 <main>:
  4004f6:       b8 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%eax
  4004fb:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000400500 <__libc_csu_init>:
  400500:       41 57                   push   %r15
  400502:       41 56                   push   %r14
  400504:       41 89 ff                mov    %edi,%r15d
  400507:       41 55                   push   %r13
  ... a bunch more code that eventually returns.
```

You could have found out what happens with a debugger, single-stepping instructions.

---

BTW, if you did make a freestanding binary, either with `gcc -static -nostartfiles` or by assembling (`as foo.s`) / linking (`ld foo.o`) yourself, you'd get an 888 byte file holding your one instruction, with the rest being ELF headers and stuff.

```
$ cat > fallthrough.s <<EOF
        .globl main
main:
    .globl _start
_start:
    mov $10, %eax
    # fall through
EOF
$ gcc -g -static -nostartfiles fallthrough.s -o fallthrough
$ gdb fallthrough
(gdb) b _start   # breakpoint
(gdb) r          # run the prog
(gdb) disassemble /r _start, _start+40
Dump of assembler code from 0x4000d4 to 0x4000fc:
=> 0x00000000004000d4 <main+0>: b8 0a 00 00 00  mov    $0xa,%eax
   0x00000000004000d9:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000db:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000dd:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000df:  00 2c 00        add    %ch,(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x00000000004000e2:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000e4:  02 00   add    (%rax),%al
   0x00000000004000e6:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000e8:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000ea:  08 00   or     %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000ec:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000ee:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000004000f0:  d4      (bad)  
   0x00000000004000f1:  00 40 00        add    %al,0x0(%rax)
   ...
(gdb) layout asm  #text-window mode. layout reg is great for single-stepping, BTW.
(gdb) si   # step instruction
0x00000000004000d9 in ?? ()
(gdb) si
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004000d9 in ?? ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

The `00` bytes that follow your code in memory are there in the ELF executable, too.  memory-mapping of files only happens with page granularity, so it all ends up mapped as executable instructions.  (machine code isn't copied out of the disk cache for executables; the memory is just mapped with read+execute permission into the process that `execve(2)`s the binary.)

```
$ objdump -s a.out
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .note.gnu.build-id:
 4000b0 04000000 14000000 03000000 474e5500  ............GNU.
 4000c0 db31c97d 55481b9a 57110753 1786dd1a  .1.}UH..W..S....
 4000d0 11679958                             .g.X
Contents of section .text:
 4000d4 b80a0000 00                          .....
Contents of section .debug_aranges:
 0000 2c000000 02000000 00000800 00000000  ,...............
 0010 d4004000 00000000 05000000 00000000  ..@.............
 0020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 ...

$ size a.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     41       0       0      41      29 a.out
```

Stripping the binary still makes it segfault, but with a different instruction.  Yay?

```
# b _start would be b *0x4000d4 without symbols.
(gdb) r
 ...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004000d9 in ?? ()
(gdb) disassemble /r $rip-5, $rip +15
Dump of assembler code from 0x4000d4 to 0x4000e8:
   0x00000000004000d4:  b8 0a 00 00 00  mov    $0xa,%eax
=> 0x00000000004000d9:  00 2e   add    %ch,(%rsi)
   0x00000000004000db:  73 68   jae    0x400145
   0x00000000004000dd:  73 74   jae    0x400153
   0x00000000004000df:  72 74   jb     0x400155
   0x00000000004000e1:  61      (bad)  
   0x00000000004000e2:  62      (bad)  
   0x00000000004000e3:  00 2e   add    %ch,(%rsi)
   0x00000000004000e5:  6e      outsb  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
   0x00000000004000e6:  6f      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
   0x00000000004000e7:  74 65   je     0x40014e

$ hexdump -C a.out
 ...
000000d0  11 67 99 58 b8 0a 00 00  00 00 2e 73 68 73 74 72  |.g.X.......shstr|
000000e0  74 61 62 00 2e 6e 6f 74  65 2e 67 6e 75 2e 62 75  |tab..note.gnu.bu|
000000f0  69 6c 64 2d 69 64 00 2e  74 65 78 74 00 00 00 00  |ild-id..text....|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

Our `mov` instruction is the `b8 0a 00 00 00` in the first line I included from the hexdump.  I think the following `00 2e ...` is an ELF data structure, probably an index of sections or something.  As an x86 instruction, it's an `add  %ch,(%rsi)`, which segfaults because `%rsi` isn't pointing to writeable memory.  (The ABI says registers other than the stack pointer are undefined on process entry, but Linux chooses to zero them in the ELF loader to avoid leaking kernel data.  `%rsi` doesn't point to writeable memory, and the process probably doesn't have any.)

---

So what if you added a return here?  Nope, there's nothing to return *to*.  The stack contains pointers to the process args environment variables.  You have to make an `exit` system call.

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
        xor %edi, %edi
        mov $231, %eax  #  exit(0)
        syscall

#       movl $1, %eax    # The 32bit ABI works even for processes in long mode, BTW.
#       int $0x80        # exit(edx)
```

Comment: Wow, I spent way longer writing this than I meant to. >.<

Comment: _"then execution would hit an"_  Hit a _what_?  ;)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks.  I just wrapped up my rambling and didn't really proofread after realizing I'd been writing this for probably over an hour, on some silly old question.