# Exit program x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, exit

I am learning x86 assembly. I am trying to understand how "exiting program" works on x86. We have a code :

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
//Some stuff here
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

When processor executes instruction "ret" :

EIP will have value, which is popped from stack, in other words 0.
so processor will go to 0 address and will try to execute instructions ... which doesn't contain program code/executable code.
So, what is really going on with processor? Are there condition check, for example, `if EIP = 0 -> exit program?` `Or if ESP out of bounds -> exit program?` `How processor understands that **this RET instruction** is the end of the program?

Comment: The notion of "program" and "exiting" are only meaningful in the context of an *operating system*. Consult your operating system's manual on how to access those concepts programmatically. (On a typical desktop OS, there would be system calls for creating and exiting a process.)

Comment: ".. popped from stack, in other words 0." How did you come to this conclusion? Is your program called "from address 0"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`main()` is called from the normal C runtime initialization functions.  Writing `main` in any language, including asm, is no different from writing any other function.

Execution begins at `_start`.  If you write your own `_start`, it has nothing to return to, so you need to make an `_exit(2)` or `exit_group(2)` system call.

(Or else segfault when execution falls off the end of your code, or if you try to `ret` it will pop a value  off the stack into the program counter (EIP), and probably segfault on code-fetch from that probably-invalid address.)

When you compile + link with a C compiler, it links in CRT (C RunTime) startup code that provides a `_start` which initializes libc then calls `main`.  **After your `main` returns, the CRT code that called it  runs `atexit` functions and then passes main's return value to an exit system call.**

`_start` isn't a function, it's the process entry point.  Under Linux for example, on entry to `_start` ESP points at `argc`, not a return address.   (See the i386 System V ABI.)

---

This question comes at the question from a different angle, but [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346474/224132) to another recent question goes into more detail.

As always, single-stepping with a debugger is a good way to see what's going on and test your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

The process gets terminated by the operating system. If you see a return instruction there is a ("hidden") function before your function, which is then given back execution.

One way of terminating the process on a Linux (32-bit) environment is by calling a specific system-call: [sys_exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_%28system_call%29)

```
mov     eax, 0 // interrupt code
mov     ebx, 0 // argument, in this case: return value
int     0x80
```

This is probably the thing the function before your function does. Above code hands command back to the operating system, which then quits your process.

Comment: `eax=0` / `int 0x80` is `sys_restart_syscall`.  **You want `mov eax, 1` for `sys_exit` in the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI**, or `eax=60` in the x86-64 `syscall` ABI.  (or `eax=231` / `syscall` for `sys_exit_group`, to exit all threads, [like libc's `exit(3)` uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit) after flushing stdio buffers and other cleanup.)  And of course `xor ebx,ebx` is the recommended way to zero a register.