# Syscall implementation of exit()

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, system-calls

I wrote a simple **C** program which just calls the [exit()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) function, however [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) says that the binary is actually calling exit_group, is exit() a exit_group() wrapper? Are these two functions equivalent? If so why would the compiler choose exit_group() over exit()?

Comment: So you load `1` in `eax` and called the kernel interrupt and `strace` shows an `exit_group` call (`252`  `0xfc`)? Which compiler? What were your compile and link strings? (it may also be a `strace` issue, though you would think they would have the lookup table right)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As far as I understand the question correctly the user is calling the `exit()` function in the `libc` library.

Comment: IIRC, that comes from standard C (and/or POSIX?) becoming thread-aware, and mandating that `exit()` should terminate all the running threads; on Linux the plain `exit`syscall would just terminate the current thread, so at some point the `exit()` libc function was remapped to the `exit_group` syscall, which does what is required by the standard.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just fixed the question,

Comment: @MartinRosenau, you may be correct, the `assembly` tag threw me off. (since assembly does have both and `exit` and `exit_group` syscall.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, More interestingly I also tried to use the _exit function from unistd.h, but nothing changed the program is still calling exit_group()

Comment: I just did a short C file and used `gcc` to dump to assembler (e.g. `gcc -S -masm=intel -o exitcall.asm exitcall.c` and the assembler instruction is `call    exit@PLT`, Running `trace` through, you are correct, I find `exit_group(0)`. I then wrote the file in assembly `nasm` and ran `strace` on the executable and it calls `exit(0)  = ?; +++ exited with 0 +++` Strange, I don't have the answer, but I now fully understand the question. Are you using `gcc` as the compiler?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yep, version 7.2

Comment: @Trey -- did you compile to object with `gas` and then link with `ld`? ... or did you let `gcc` handle the link? If so, it would be interesting to know what options `gcc` used by default. For my x86 example, I compiled with `nasm`, e.g. `nasm -f elf -o ./obj/exitcall32.o exitcall32.asm` and linked with `ld -m elf_i386 -o ./bin/exitcall32 ./obj/exitcall32.o`. There are differences in entry point (`main` v. `_start`) which may pull in the libc `exit_group` if you compiled and let `gcc` do the link.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I used **as** and then **ld**, without any flags, and i'm using a 64-bit machine

Comment: @Trey: Did you use `eax=1` / `int $0x80` in 64-bit code?  If so, strace decodes it wrong, but it really is `sys_exit()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code.  Works for me with `cat > foo.S` / copy-paste your code / `gcc -m32 foo.S -nostdlib -static` && `strace a.out`.  I get `exit(0)`.  In 64-bit a executable, strace decodes it as `write(0, NULL, 0)` and then says `+++ exited with 0 +++`.  So I can't reproduce your `exit_group` from eax=1 / `int $0x80`

Comment: Either change your question back to the old one, or update it with a [mcve] for strace decoding eax=1 / `int $0x80` as `exit(0)`.  It's just weird now, because that's a pretty different question from asking about what the C library wrapper functions do (and why).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Linux and glibc man pages document all of this (See especially the "C library/kernel differences" in the NOTES section).

- [`_exit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html): In glibc 2.3 and later, this wrapper function actually uses the Linux `SYS_exit_group` system call to exit all threads.  Before glibc2.3, it was a wrapper for `SYS_exit` to exit just the current thread.
- [`exit_group(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html): glibc wrapper for `SYS_exit_group`, which exits all threads.
- [`exit(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html): The ISO C89 function which flushes buffers and then exits the whole process. (It always uses `exit_group()` because there's no benefit to checking if the process was single-threaded and deciding to use `SYS_exit` vs. `SYS_exit_group`).  [As @Matteo points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit/46903734#comment80753101_46903180), recent ISO C / POSIX standards are thread-aware and one or both probably require this behaviour.

  But apparently `exit(3)` itself is not thread-safe (in the C library cleanup parts), so I guess don't call it from multiple threads at once.
- `syscall` / `int 0x80` with `SYS_exit`: terminates just the current thread, leaving others running.  AFAIK, modern glibc has no thin wrapper function for this Linux system call, but I think `pthread_exit()` uses it if this isn't the last thread.  (Otherwise exit(3) -> exit_group(2).)

Only `exit()`, not `_exit()` or `exit_group()`, flushes `stdout`, leading to "`printf` doesn't print anything" problems in newbie asm programs if writing to a pipe (which makes `stdout` full-buffered instead of line-buffered), or if you forgot the `\n` in the format string.  For example, [How come _exit(0) (exiting by syscall) prevents me from receiving any stdout content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755027/how-come-exit0-exiting-by-syscall-prevents-me-from-receiving-any-stdout-con).  If you use any buffered I/O functions, or `at_exit`, or anything like that, it's usually a good idea to call the libc `exit(3)` function instead of the system call directly.  But of course you can call `fflush` before `SYS_exit_group`.

(Also related: [On x64 Linux, what is the difference between syscall, int 0x80 and ret to exit a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676658/on-x64-linux-what-is-the-difference-between-syscall-int-0x80-and-ret-to-exit-a) - `ret` from main is equivalent to calling `exit(3)`)

---

It's not of course the *compiler* that chose anything, it's libc.  When you include headers and write `read(fd, buf, 123)` or `exit(1)`, the C compiler just sees an ordinary function call.

Some C libraries (e.g. [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/), but not glibc) may use inline asm to inline a `syscall` instruction into your binary, but still the headers are part of the C library, not the compiler.

Comment: To be honest, you beat me to the man pages.... and again I learn how much I've still to learn. Thanks Peter.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I didn't have to look this up just now; I was curious about it years ago. :P  I learned a *lot* of systems programming stuff just from reading Linux man pages and seeing what various programs did using `strace`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: This is the way.  The complexity is reflected by the evolution of threading on Linux **systems** over time and the fact that the syscall mechanics remain in the API even after a better mechanism is found.  I say **system** to emphasize the interplay of kernel, libc and compilers.