# How does the function _exit() in glibc looks like?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls, glibc

I am studying C and Operating system, during which i came across the system call `exit()` in *nix systems. 
I know there will be wrapper procedure call in C for each of the system call in *nix systems. In this case, `exit()` is the procedure call provided in the standard C library, let us consider glibc for the discussion. 
I have downloaded the glibc code and checked the code inside `exit()` it finally makes a call to `_exit()`.
where can i find the function body of `_exit()`?
In library glibc, would the function `_exit()` be making a system call `exit()` in case of UNIX and `ExitProcess()` in case of Windows, based on the operating system?

Comment: Did you try checking "Termination Internals" section? Here [is the link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Internals.html)

Comment: It does not explain my question, though.
I want to understand whether _exit () would call different system calls based on the operating system. exit () in case of Unix OS and ExitProcess () in case of windows?

Comment: The answer is yes. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit)

Comment: *exit () in case of Unix OS* On Solaris, [the system call may be called `exit`, but it calls `rexit()`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/os/sysent.c#437) and thus shows up in dTrace as `rexit`. Unless you're actually doing *direct system calls* (and even if you use the `syscall()` **function** you are not doing actual system calls...) you're making function calls. How your code's *function* calls map to actual system calls isn't as direct as those who break `libc.so` into "functions" and "aystem calls" would lead you to believe. It's all very platform-specific

Comment: Where to check function definition for _exit ()?
I don't see it under exit.c file