# Assembly code to terminate thread in Arm Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, system-calls, kill

I want to write short Arm Linux assembly code that terminate the thread that call it.

**I can't call to function (3)  only syscall**

I think to get my tid with `gettid(2)` and then send `tkill(2)` to this tid?

```
mov     %r7, $0xe0   /* gettid is syscall #0xe0 */
swi     $0          /* invoke syscall */
/*r0 contains current tid*/

mov     %r1, $9 /* SIGKILL signal */
mov     %r7, $0xee   /* tkill is syscall #0xee */
swi     $0          /* invoke syscall */
```

Does the code above work? What is the easy and short way?

Comment: `tkill` doesn't terminate a thread.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. So what is the way to kill thread with assembly?

Comment: There is no way to kill a threat that doesn't want to die.

Answer (score 1):

Testing a C version first with symbols rather than hard-coded values using  `musl-libc` - you can retrieve [syscall.h.in](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/arm/bits/syscall.h.in) and [syscall_arch.h](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/arch/arm/syscall_arch.h) form its git repository.

`pthread_exit.c` - calling `_gettid` system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "syscall.h.in"
#include "syscall_arch.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  long pid =  __syscall0(__NR_gettid); 
  printf("pid: %ld\n", pid);
//__syscall2(__NR_tkill, pid, SIGKILL); 
  printf("Kilroy should not be here.\n");
}

gcc -o pthread_exit pthread_exit.c

./pthread_exit
pid: 14494
Kilroy should not be here.
./pthread_exit
pid: 14495
Kilroy should not be here.
./pthread_exit
pid: 14496
Kilroy should not be here.
```

`pthread_exit.c` - calling `_gettid` and `tkill` system calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "syscall.h.in"
#include "syscall_arch.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  long pid =  __syscall0(__NR_gettid); 
  printf("pid: %ld\n", pid);
  __syscall2(__NR_tkill, pid, SIGKILL); 
  printf("Kilroy should not be here.\n");
}

gcc -o pthread_exit pthread_exit.c
./pthread_exit
pid: 14513
Killed
./pthread_exit
pid: 14514
Killed
./pthread_exit
pid: 14515
Killed
```

Looking at `syscall_arch.h`:

```
static inline long __syscall0(long n)
{
    register long r7 __ASM____R7__ = n;
    register long r0 __asm__("r0");
    __asm_syscall(R7_OPERAND);
}

static inline long __syscall2(long n, long a, long b)
{
    register long r7 __ASM____R7__ = n;
    register long r0 __asm__("r0") = a;
    register long r1 __asm__("r1") = b;
    __asm_syscall(R7_OPERAND, "0"(r0), "r"(r1));
}
```

As you had figured out, the number for the desired system call should reside in `r7`, and parameters are in `r0` to `r5` - we just need `r0` and `r1` here.

So, yes, it works:
`pthread_exit.s`:

```
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv7-a
        .fpu vfpv3-d16
        .text
        .align  2
        .global main
        .thumb
        .thumb_func
        .type   main, %function
main:
        mov     %r7, $0xe0   /* gettid is syscall #0xe0 */
        swi     $0          /* invoke syscall */
        /*r0 contains current tid*/
        mov     %r1, $9 /* SIGKILL signal */
        mov     %r7, $0xee   /* tkill is syscall #0xee */
        swi     $0          /* invoke syscall */
       .end
```

Using `qemu-user`:

```
qemu-arm pthread_exit
Killed
```

On a `Cortex-A7` system:

```
 ./pthread_exit
Killed
```

Not sure this is the correct way to go though - see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit).

Comment: [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46903180) that you linked is about making the current thread (or all threads) exit, not *just* another thread but not the current.  I would have assumed that `tgkill` is the right way to forcibly terminate another thread, although normally you'd have your other threads run code that chooses to exit after seeing some value in shared variables.

Comment: I see, thanks for this precision.in another vein, I would probably rather use `tgkill`, which obsoleted `tkill`.

Comment: @Frant, can you please explain  more? If I want that my thread will suicide ,so `gettid` and `tkill` is the right way,but of I want to kill another thread `tkill` is not the right way? Why is that?

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom: This is not what I meant, I was just wondering if there was a less brutal way of doing it. It should  work I guess on another thread as well.

Comment: @Frant, the problem is that `tkill` kill all the process.not only the current thread, do you have  another idea?

Comment: I understood your question as: "does my assembly program work the same way the equivalent C program would", and answered yes. If that was not the question you intended to ask, just tell me, I will remove my answer it since it will be irrelevant. You may want to rephrase your question in this case though. And yes, it seems `tkill() ` does kill both the child thread and the main thread. A look at the source code for the `pthread` library would likely provide some insights.