# Can't understand the line-based execution flow of assembly

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm studing procedures of Assembly Language in Hack The Box platform.

The Code:

```
global  _start

section .data
    message db "Fibonacci Sequence:", 0x0a

section .text
_start:
    call printMessage   ; print intro message
    call initFib        ; set initial Fib values
    call loopFib        ; calculate Fib numbers
    call Exit           ; Exit the program

printMessage:
    mov rax, 1      ; rax: syscall number 1
    mov rdi, 1      ; rdi: fd 1 for stdout
    mov rsi,message ; rsi: pointer to message
    mov rdx, 20     ; rdx: print length of 20 bytes
    syscall         ; call write syscall to the intro message
    ret

initFib:
    xor rax, rax    ; initialize rax to 0
    xor rbx, rbx    ; initialize rbx to 0
    inc rbx         ; increment rbx to 1
    ret

loopFib:
    add rax, rbx    ; get the next number
    xchg rax, rbx   ; swap values
    cmp rbx, 10     ; do rbx - 10
    js loopFib      ; jump if result is <0
    ret

Exit:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

There is a note that I don't understand.

> Note: It is important to understand the line-based execution flow of assembly. If we don't use a ret at the end of a procedure it will simply execute the next line. Likewise, had we returned at the end of our Exit function, we would simply go back and execute the next line, which would be the first line of printMessage.

**My question is:**

The Exit procedure (subroutine) is the last one so how the next instruction will be executed after it will be the first one which is the first instruction in the "printMessage".

I've encountered some info wrong on this platform so I've decided to check it my self throw gdb debugger and it's indeed true.

[image]

Update:

I've tried to remove the syscall and add ret and see what will happen and it called printMessage again but when it hit the ret, the program stopped the rsp doesn't point to the next instruction.

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious from the code, but the `syscall` in the `Exit:` section actually terminates the program, so the call to `Exit` never gets a chance to return. If it had, you are correct that control flow would fall through to `printMessage`, which would not make sense.

Comment: *possible* duplicate (at least near) of [What if there is no return statement in a CALLed block of code in assembly programs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205054) - where `_start` is the block of code that would fall through into what's next if `call Exit` ever returned.  (But note that the entry point `_start` isn't a function, so `ret` would just segfault, that's why this program makes an exit system call.  [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760002))

Comment: Another example of fall-through into whatever's next: [Why is no value returned if a function does not explicity use 'ret'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20578122).  The key point being that a label like `printMessage:` doesn't stop execution from falling into it, it's just a zero-width marker in case you want to refer to that position from elsewhere.  The instructions are still contiguous.  This is the concept your book is explaining.

Comment: I've read them they actually not like mine so i didn't get somthing useful. @PeterCordes

Comment: @MohamedTaha: I'm not sure what part of your book you're not understanding.  That paragraph is talking about replacing the `syscall` instruction in the `Exit:` block with a `ret` instruction.  According to your update, that's what you tried.  That's exactly what the book was trying to show you, that you fall through "off the end" of the `start:` block. And since execution eventually reaches another `ret` instruction when RSP doesn't point at a valid return address, it crashes. The book didn't talk about that part, they were just describing the fall-through if a noreturn function returned.

Comment: You do see that `message` gets written to stdout twice, right?  That system call happens before it crashes, and doesn't depend on any function args passed by `_start` or on stack alignment.

Comment: To be clear, what I don't understand is how after the call of Exit (when Exit return) the rip points to printMessage again? @PeterCordes

Comment: You're looking at it in the debugger.  The return address pushed by `call Exit` is the address of the next instruction, the `mov rax, 1` in `printMessage`.  That's what a `ret` there would pop into RIP, as explained in some of the Q&As I linked earlier.

Comment: why the address of `mov rax, 1` in `printMessage` is poped into RIP? @PeterCordes

Comment: Because it's the next instruction in memory after `call Exit`, so that's the return address it pushes.  Because it's the next line of asm source that emits any bytes into the output (not just a label).

Comment: I know making huge effort explaining to me but I still don't understand how the `mov rax, 1` in `printMessage` in the RSP while the `Exit` is the last label there is nothing to execute further. @PeterCordes

Comment: @MohamedTaha: We're talking about a modified version of the code with `Exit: ret`, so it does return to the end of `_start:`, from where execution falls through past the `printMessage:` label.  With that in mind as what you need to understand, go read the early comments *and the linked Q&As* again.  And just try it single-stepping in a debugger.  It might be easier to understand if you put something after the `call Exit` before the label, like `call Exit`  `add eax, 1` ; `nop` or something, so the "fall-through" out of the "block" starting at `_start:` is separate from the return.