# Where to check shell returned values descriptions

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

When we *execute any C program* in unix/linux *without returning any value*, shell returns some value.

In my case, it returned **11**

**My program is simple:**

```
main(){
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

**Output:**

Hello World
**Shell returned 11**

Where to see the description of *"Shell returned 11"*

Comment: This is not a valid C program, since it doesn't declare the `main` function correctly. A conforming *standard* C implementation would return a "success" state.

Comment: you are doing wrong thing, 
printf("Hello World");

printf is reading 11 bytes .thats what echo $? is showing you

Comment: With C99 or C++ the return value will default to 0. Otherwise the return value is undefined. The fact that you got 11 is just meaningless. Return a value if you want to see the result using $? from the shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix and Linux systems, the value returned to the shell by a C program is either

- 256+the signal number if the program terminated due to a signal
- the lowest 8 bits of the value passed to a call to `exit` or `_exit`
- the lowest 8 bits of the value in a `return` statement in `main`
- if compiled with a C99-standard compiler and `main` is declared to return a value compatible with int, then falling off the end of `main` will result in an exit value of 0.
- undefined behavior

In your case, it was undefined behavior. It looks like the return value from `printf` was 11, because that's the number of characters that were written. Since there were no intervening function calls between the call to `printf` and the end of `main`, this value remained in the register where function return values are stored.

**You can't rely on this behavior.** It will vary depending on the compiler, runtime library, and operating system. It is best to call `exit` or to use a `return` statement in `main` with a value.

There are some conventions for exit code values. See [Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux).

Comment: You are right Mr. Mark, I tried same with other strings, and it returned exact length of the string.
Thank You.

Comment: I added the C99 case, courtesy of Brandin and mafso.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler understood implicitly that `main` returns an int. You should compile with -Wall to this warning (and many other useful ones).
Change to:

```
int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0; // success
}
```

Or:

```
void main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    // returns zero to the shell unless exit(SOME_NON_ZERO_VALUE) was called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the string(passed in "" to printf function) length returned by shell.

Answer posted by Mark Plotnick is right as I verified it and tried with different parameters to printf() function.

Thank you all for your replies.