# exit(); is not working

Tags: c, exit, exit-code

In my programming book, it shows me exit used without any parameters(`exit();`).
Unfortunately it does not work.

Some people have said use `exit(0);` while some say `exit(1); exit(2);` and `exit(3)`;
What is the difference between them and is there even an `exit(4);` ?

The funny thing is that my compiler does not need `stdlib.h` to execute `exit(0);` and the rest.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux not quite a duplicate... but pretty close.

Comment: Your compiler does not execute function `exit`. It simply compiles the call to `exit(0)` into a few op-codes for pushing `0` into the stack, and then jumping (changing the instruction-pointer) to the address of function `exit`, within the code-section of your executable image. And since the address of that function is not known during compilation, it is the linker which replaces the symbol `exit` with the actual address. So to summarize this - the compiler replaces `exit(0)` with binary code for jumping to a function, and the linker updates that binary code with the address of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to the 1999 version of the ISO C standard, it was legal to call a function with no visible declaration. The compiler would *assume* that the function exists, creating an implicit declaration. (It would also assume that it returns a result of type `int`, which `exit()` does not.) If this implicit declaration doesn't match the actual definition of the function, the behavior is undefined.

As of the 1999 standard, the "implicit `int`" rule was dropped, and a call without a visible declaration (as provided, in this case, by `#include <stdlib.h>`) became invalid. Even though it's invalid, a compiler may still issue a non-fatal warning and handle it under the older rules; gcc does this by default.

Under any version of the language, `exit` requires a single argument of type `int`. Passing `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` (a macro defined in `<stdlib.h>` causes the program to terminate and pass a status to the environment indicating success. Passing `EXIT_FAILURE` causes the program to terminate with a status indicating failure.

The meanings of other argument values are not specified by the C language. You'll commonly see `exit(1)` to denote failure, but that's not entirely portable.

(`exit` may be some kind of built-in function in gcc, but that doesn't affect the rules of the language; it's still invalid to call `exit` with no visible declaration, or to call it without an `int` argument. If it's built-in, that might affect the level of detail in the diagnostic message.)

Answer (score 4):

```
void exit( int exit_code );
```

Here, `exit_code` is the exit status of the program. After calling this, control is returned to the host environment. If `exit_code` is `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined status, indicating successful termination is returned. If `exit_code` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined status, indicating unsuccessful termination is returned. **In other cases implementation-defined status value is returned**.

Check out [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) for more info.

---

**P.S.:** The reason that your compiler does not need `stdlib.h` to execute `exit(0);` maybe either it has been include by other headers that included in your code or, as @devnull mentioned, when building using `gcc` where `exit()` is one of the built-in functions.

Comment: Usually the exit code is only relevant to whoever or whatever called the program. By convention, an exit code of 0 usually indicates success and non-zero exit codes represent specific errors as defined for the program. But this is only a convention. Do you know if `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` actually have any meaning in the program itself? I.e., does `exit` behave differently depending on which value you pass it?

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm After calling this, control is returned to the host environment. It will be meaningful if the host environment need to handle according this returned status.

Comment: It doesn't matter than `exit` is a built-in function. gcc is following C90 rules, which means it assumes a declaration for `exit` if none is visible. You'll see the same behavior for any undeclared function, built-in or not, though gcc may give more detailed diagnostics for built-in functions.

Comment: what is exit failure? if you wanted it to exit and it did, why is it a failure?

Comment: @user3328692 It means something happens and you want to notice the host environment after its termination.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Do you mean the parameters only mater, if you want to know the exit status. So if you do not want to know the exit status it does not matter what parameter you put in like exit(347);

Comment: @user3328692 If the host also thinks so. :P

Comment: @herohuyongtao i dont get you? what host? i am new to coding

Answer (score 3):

> The funny thing is that my compiler does not need stdlib.h to execute
>   exit(0);and the rest.

You seem to be using `gcc`.  `exit` is one of the [built-in functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) provided by gcc, due to which you do not need the specified header.

The parameter passed to `exit()` is used to indicate termination status.

Comment: The fact that `exit` is built-in probably doesn't matter. I think you'll see the same behavior for any call to an undeclared function.

Answer (score 0):

`exit(0)` with a `0` is sent by a process if it has ended correctly. The other numbers are used when the exit has been produced with some kind of error.

At the same time that you allow the parent process to catch exit signals from its child processes with `waitpid`:

- in this way if you make processes end concurrently:  `while(waitpid(1,&exit_code,0) > 0)`, where `exit_code` is an integer that gets the exit code of the finished process
- or in this way: `waitpid(-1,NULL,0)` if you make them finish sequentially

you can get the exit status of child processes if you put this code after `waitpid` or into `waitpid`'s loop:

```
pid = waitpid(-1, &exit_code, 0);  //getting the finished process' PID

if (WIFEXITED(exit_code)) { 

int statcode = WEXITSTATUS(exit_code); 
printf(“Process with PID %d has finished with status %d, pid, statcode); 

}
```

try this if you want to make sure that `exit()` works

Answer (score 0):

Just use the <stdlib.h> header file and things will work!