# system() Returning Wrong Value

Tags: embedded, arm, embedded-linux

I have an ARM-based device running Embedded Linux and I have observed that when I use the C library's **system()** call, the return code is incorrect. Here is a test program that demonstrates the behavior:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret = system("exit 42");
    printf("Should return 42 for system() call: %d\n", ret);
    printf("Returning 43 to shell..\n");
    exit(43);
};
```

And here is the program output on the device:

```
# returnCodeTest                 
Should return 42 for system() call: 10752
Returning 43 to shell..
```

The value "10752" is returned by system() instead of "42". 10752 is 42 when left-shifted by 8:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 42<<8
10752
```

So is suspect one of the following is going on somewhere:

1. The byte order is getting swapped
2. The value is getting shifted by 8 bits
3. Incompatible struct definitions are being used

When I run strace I see the following:

```
# strace /usr/bin/returnCodeTest 
...
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x4001e308) = 977
wait4(977, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 42}], 0, NULL) = 977
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=977, si_status=42, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0622, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x4001f000
write(1, "Should return 42 for system() ca"..., 42Should return 42 for system() call: 10752
) = 42
write(1, "Returning 43 to shell..\n", 24Returning 43 to shell..
) = 24
exit_group(43)                          = ?
+++ exited with 43 +++
```

**wait4()** returns with the correct status (si_status=42), but when it gets printed to standard output the value is shifted by 8 bits, and it looks like it is happening in a library. Interestingly the write returns a value of 42. I wonder if this is a hint as to what is going on...

Unfortunately I cannot get ltrace to compile and run on the device. Has anyone seen this type of behavior before or have any ideas (possibly architecture-specific) on where to look?

Comment: do you have the source for the standard library?  It seems like the definition of `system` is the obvious place to start. I'd guess that it's making wrong assumptions about how to extract the `si_status` bits from the wait4 result.

Comment: The return value of `system` is implementation-defined, so it's only "incorrect" if it differs from what your C library documentation says it should be. @auselen's answer would appear to be appropriate, if a little terse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $man 3 system
>
> Return Value
>
> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is
>   in the format specified in wait(2). **Thus, the exit code of the command
>   will be WEXITSTATUS(status)**.
>
> $man 2 wait
>
> WEXITSTATUS(status) returns the exit status of the child. This
>   consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that
>   the child specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the
>   argument for a return statement in main(). This macro should only be
>   employed if WIFEXITED returned true.

Comment: When I replace the "ret" with "WEXITSTATUS(ret)" in the first printf call, the correct value appears in standard output. It was in the man pages all along... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think exit codes are different from return values and is specific to OS.

Linux does the following when you call "exit" with a code.

**(error_code&0xff)<<8**

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(exit, int, error_code)
{
        do_exit((error_code&0xff)<<8);
}
```

Take look at the below link (exit status codes in Linux).

[Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)