# Perl: After a successful system call, "or die" command still ends script

Tags: perl, system-calls, die

I am using the following line to make a simple system call which works:

```
system ("mkdir -p Purged") or die "Failed to mkdir." ;
```

Executing the script does make the system call and I can find a directory called Purged, but the error message is still printed and the script dies. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Avoid `system` when Perl provides a built-in equivalent. Use `make_path` from [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html) instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> That would be a little confusing, wouldn't? -  Leonardo Herrera on [Ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763247/368630)

Yes, it is confusing that the `system` command inverts true and false in Perl, and creates fun logic like this:

```
if ( system qw($command) ) {
    die qq(Aw... If failed);
}
else {
    say qq(Hooray! It worked!);
}
```

But, it's understandable why the `system` command does this. In Unix, an *exit status* of zero means the program worked, and a non-zero status could give you information why your `system` call failed. Maybe the program you were calling doesn't exist. Maybe the program sort of worked as expected. For example, `grep` returns an exit code of `1` when `grep` works, but there were no matching lines. You might want to distinguish when `grep` returns zero, one, or a return code greater than one. (Yes, I know it's silly to use a system call to `grep` in a Perl program, but that's the first example I could think of).

To prevent casual confusion, I create a variable that holds the exit status of my `system` command instead of testing the output of `system` directly:

```
my $error = system qw($command);
if ($error) {
    die qq(Aw... It failed);
}
else {
    say qq(Hooray! It worked!);
}
```

It's completely unnecessary, and people who work with Perl should know that `system` reverses Perl's definition of *true* and *false*, but if I hadn't had my coffee in the morning, I may miss it as I go over someone else's code. Doing this little step just makes the program look a bit more logical.

The Perldoc of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) give you code that allows you to test the output of your system command to see exactly what happened. (If there was an error, or a system interrupt signal killed the `system` call). It's nice to know if you need to interrogate your `system` return value to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: system doesn't really reverse anything, and that's not a good way to think about it. The system command returns something and you should understand the exit values of the program and know what to check. The `system` does not return a value that indicates if the command worked, and some are "successful" but have non-zero exit values.

Answer (score 20):

`system` returns the exit status of the command it calls. In shell, zero exit status means success. You have to invert the logic:

```
0 == system qw(mkdir -p Purged) or die "Failed to create the dir\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

`system` returns `0` on success, so you want `and` rather than `or`.

See also: `use autodie qw( system );`

Comment: That would be a little confusing, wouldn't?

Comment: That's fine! Simple code is always the best solution :)

Comment: This isn't really true. `system` returns the exit value of the program. In Unix, most of the time, programs return 0 to mean success and non-zero for other things. However, some programs use non-zero exit statuses to mean other types of success. `system` is not judging or interpreting: it's passing through.

Answer (score 3):

To add what hasn't been mentioned but what comes with it and can quietly mess things up.

The `system`'s return of 'zero-or-not' only tells whether the command itself executed successfully, by shell or `execvp`; the `0` *does not* mean that the command succeeded in what it was doing.<sup>†</sup>

In case of non-zero return you need to unpack `$?` for more information;<sup>†</sup> see [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for how to do this. For one, the command's actual exit code is `$? >> 8`, what the executed program was designed to communicate at its exit.

Altogether you may want to do something to the effect of

```
sub run_system {
    my ($cmd, @other_agrs) = @_;             # may do more via @other_args

    my ($cmdref, $sys_ret) = (ref $cmd, 0);  # LIST or scalar invocation?
    if ($cmdref eq 'ARRAY') {
        $sys_ret = system(@$cmd);
    }
    elsif (not $cmdref) {
        $sys_ret = system($cmd);
    }
    else { Carp::carp "Invocation error, got $cmdref" }

    return 1 if $sys_ret == 0;

    # Still here? The rest is error handling.
    # (Or handling of particular non-zero returns; see text footnote)
    Carp::carp "Trouble with 'system($cmd)': $?";
    print "Got exit " . ($? >> 8) . " from $cmd\n";
    return 0;  # or Carp::croak (but then design changes)
}
```

This can be done merely as `system == 0 or do { ... };` or such right in the code, but this way there's a little library, where we can refine error handling more easily, eventually decide to switch to a module to manage external commands, etc. Also, being a user-level facility now it makes sense that it returns true on success (we aren't changing `system`'s design).

Additionally in this case, `mkdir -p` is meant to be quiet and it may not say anything when it cannot do its thing, in some cases. This is by design of course, but one should be aware of it.

---

<sup>†</sup>  A program may return whatever it wants; nothing requires of it to return zero if it succeeded (completed without error) and it does not have to follow any conventions; what it returns is entirely up to its design.

Typical Unix programs generally follow the convention of returning non-zero only if there were problems, but some do return non-zero values merely to indicate a particular condition. See for example [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux).

One example: for at least some versions, `zip` returns non-zero (12) when it "*has nothing to do*" (nothing to update in a package for example), even though it completes successfully; so we get 3072 from `system` in that case (when that 12 is packed into high bits of a number which is the return code). This is documented on its man page.

A zero return, though, normally does imply a successful operation, what is the main point here.

Comment: Edited to state that some programs may return non-zero even if they ran without error, merely to indicate a particular condition: added a footnote, a parenthetical remark, and a line of comment in code. This _does not change_ the point of this answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest
`system ("mkdir -p Purged") && die "Failed to mkdir.";`

Answer (score 0):

The `system` command passes through the exit code of the program that it ran. It doesn't judge or interpret it. [Raku, on the other hand, does interpret it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43199427/2766176) and you have to fight the language to get around it. And, remember that Perl's `system` is basically C's `system` (and many things in Perl are just what C's version does).

You need to compare this to the value you expected based on your knowledge of that particular command's behavior, as shown in the [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) docs:

```
@args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
system(@args) == 0
    or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

Usually, well made unix programs use 0 to indicate success and non-zero for everything else. That's a good rule of thumb, but it's a convention rather than a requirement. Some programs return non-zero values to  indicate other sorts of success. `system` knows none of that. Not only that, many programmers have no idea what an exit code should be, and I've often had to deal with someone's reinvented idea of what that should be (and I've probably done that myself at some point).

There's been a growing trend of "trust and don't verify", which I think is the new generation of programmers not having systems and shell programming backgrounds. And, even then, there's how the world should be and how it actually is. Remember, your goal as the programmer is to know what happened and why, even if the world is messy.

Here are a few interesting links:

- [Well Behaved Non-Zero Exit Codes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345817/12567)
- [Non-zero exit status for clean exit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/153926/103630)
- [Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101957/2766176)

I like [this statement from Frederick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30747662/2766176) the best, though:

> More realistically, 0 means success or maybe failure, 1 means general failure or maybe success, 2 means general failure if 1 and 0 are both used for success, but maybe success as well.

Consider `grep`. Here's a file to search:

```
$ cat original.txt
This is the original
This is from append.txt
This is from append.txt
This is from append.txt
```

Search for something that exists:

```
$ grep original original.txt
This is the original
```

The exit code is 0 (`$?` on the shell, but Perl's `$?` is more complicated). That's what you expect by convention. You found something and there were no errors:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

But now search for something that doesn't exist. You don't find something but there were no errors:

```
$ grep foo original.txt
```

Now the exit code is 1, because that's what `grep` does:

```
$ echo $?
1
```

This is non-zero but not an error. You called `grep` correctly and it produced the correct and expected output.

It's not up to `system` to judge those exit values. It passes through that exit code and lets you interpret them.

Now, we get lazy and assume that 0 means that it worked. We do that because many people are used to seeing it and it works most of the time. But, "works most if the time" is different than "won't bite me in the ass". Compare the result to `system` to exactly what you will accept as success:

```
my $expected = 0;
system('...') == $expected or die ...
```

If the task's definition of success is that `grep` finds matching lines, that code works fine because the exit code in that case happens to be zero. But, that accidentally works because two different ideas happen to align at that one point.

But, what you accept as success is not the same thing as the exit code. Consider that `grep` example. So far you know that both `0` and `1` are normal operation. Both of those mean that `grep` did not encounter an error. That's different than calling `grep` incorrectly and getting a different exit value:

```
$ grep -X foo original.txt
grep: original.txt: Undefined error: 0

$ echo $?
2
```

That `2` is conventionally used to signal that you called the program incorrectly. For example, you are using switches that exist on one implementation of a tool that don't exist on another (there are other things than line and gnu, but less so).

You might end up with something like this:

```
my %acceptable = map { $_ => 1 } qw(0 1);
my $rc = system(...);
die ... unless exists $acceptable{$rc};
```

And, the `die` can pass through that exit code (see it's [method for choosing a value](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die)):

```
$ perl -e 'system( "grep -X foo original.txt" ) == 0 or die'
grep: original.txt: Undefined error: 0
Died at -e line 1.

$ echo $?
2
```

Sure, that's not as pretty as the single statement, but pretty shouldn't trump correct.

But that's not even good enough. My linux version of `grep` says it will exit with `0` on error in certain conditions:

> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and  2  if  an  error  occurred. However,  if  the  -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

Going a step further, there's a list of conventional exit codes in *sysexits.h* that signal very particular conditions. For example, that exit code of 2 gets the symbol `EX_USAGE` and indicates a problem with the way the command was formed.

When I'm writing system code, I'm hard core on proper exit codes so other programs can know what happened without parsing error output. The `die` called by the user without a failure in a `system` will probably return 255. That's not very useful for other things to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

A one-line solution:

```
system("if printf '' > tmp.txt; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi ;") or die("unable to clobber tmp.txt");
```