# Why doesn't Perl 6's try handle a non-zero exit in shell()?

Tags: exception, raku

This [try](https://docs.raku.org/language/exceptions#index-entry-try_blocks-try) catches the exception:

```
try die X::AdHoc;
say "Got to the end";
```

The output shows that the program continues:

```
 Got to the end
```

If I attempt it with `shell` and a command that doesn't exit with 0, the try doesn't catch it:

```
try shell('/usr/bin/false');
say "Got to the end";
```

The output doesn't look like an exception:

```
The spawned command '/usr/bin/false' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1)
  in block <unit> at ... line ...
```

What's going on that this makes it through the try?

Comment: FWIW, this smells like a bug.  Please rakudobug it!

Comment: Will look into this. I also assume I'm the first problem. :)

Comment: It's worth noting Proc object's .Bool is false when the exit is non-zero, so one way to test failure is to just use that Bool:


    `"false".&shell or say "tis no good!";`

Answer (score 5):

The answer is really provided by Jonathan Worthington:

```
https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6-dev/2017-04-04#i_14372945
```

In short, shell() returns a Proc object.  The moment that object is sunk, it will throw the exception that it has internally if running the program failed.

```
$ 6 'dd shell("/usr/bin/false")'
Proc.new(in => IO::Pipe, out => IO::Pipe, err => IO::Pipe, exitcode => 1, signal => 0, command => ["/usr/bin/false"])
```

So, what you need to do is catch the Proc object in a variable, to prevent it from being sunk:

```
$ 6 'my $result = shell("/usr/bin/false"); say "Got to the end"'
Got to the end
```

And then you can use $result.exitcode to see whether it was successful or not.

Comment: And if explosion is wanted, one can do `try sink shell 'false'` to sink the `Proc` *inside* the `try`.