# exit status of ./a.out (c compiled code) on running it

Tags: php, c, bash, shell

I have a c compiled code.
I am using

```
exec('./a.out 2>&1',$out,$ret);
```

in my php script to get return type where I want to know first whether it ran fine or what went wrong a segmentation fault or infinite loop or something like that.
basically i want to know the exit status 0,1 and 2 and there significance.
if any other exit status exist please tell those also..

Comment: Actually, an infinite loop would not return anything, as the program would keep running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

PHP puts the exit status of the exec()ed program to the `$ret` variable. The program has exited successfully iff `$ret` becomes 0 after exec() returns.