# Running bash commands in python and handling errors

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

I am trying to run a set of bash script commands in a python program. I have to run the commands one by one and handle errors and exceptions for each command. For this purpose, I am using the `subprocess` module with the `call` function as bellow:

```
result = subprocess.call("echo testing", shell = True)
```

as expected this command prints "testing" and sets the value of `result` to 0, meaning that the command was successfully executed. Or, in the case of following command:

```
result = subprocess.call("echso testing", shell = True)
```

it prints "/bin/sh: 1: echso: not found" and sets the value of `result` to 127, meaning that the command `echso` is invalid. 
My qusetion is, where can I find a complete list of these error numbers with descriptions that I could use for error handling? So far, I found a list of exit errors as follows:

```
1: general errors
2: misuse of shell builtins (pretty rare)
126: cannot invoke requested command
127: command not found error
128: invalid argument to “exit”
128+n: fatal error signal “n” (for example, kill -9 = 137)
130: script terminated by Ctrl-C
```

Is this all, or do you know more error codes with descriptions?

Comment: That list you have is about as good as it gets. Each program is free to use whatever exit codes it wants. You really can't rely on anything besides "nonzero equals error." That said, you can capture `stderr` and offer to present that to the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash man page has a section [3.7.5 Exit Status](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Exit-Status) which covers the values you indicated (though I don't see 130 in there).

Beyond that I don't know that there is any good standard.

There is [sysexits.h](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.3-RELEASE&format=html) but I'm not sure how much anyone actually uses it (available on linux also).

Comment: That is why i prefer the other solution.It at least handles all the cases

Comment: @vks No, it doesn't handle all the cases. It doesn't handle things that don't write to stderr but return a failure return code.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = subprocess.Popen("echo testing", shell = True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err=result.communicate()
if output:
    print "success"
else:
    print err
```

Instead of finding errors to numbers you can find errors directly and handle them.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: How does this answer the question of where he can find a list of exit coder for the shell?

Comment: This gives you standard error from the run command (I believe) that's not always the same thing.

Comment: @EtanReisner he basically wants to handle errors.I guess this is a fine way to that

Comment: Except that isn't the question he actually asked and this covers a slightly different case. But yes, in general this is a reasonable alternative suggestion but that should be more clearly explained and with the reasons why.

Comment: @vks thanks for the answer. your code results in this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a02/workspace/test/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = subprocess.Popen("echo testing", shell = True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.Popen)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1065, in _get_handles
    errwrite = stderr.fileno()
AttributeError: type object 'Popen' has no attribute 'fileno'
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user823743 Typo `stderr=subprocess.Popen` should be `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much mentioned all of them. A more elaborate list is given [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF), and here's some useful info about each of them:

[image: reserved exit codes]

> According to the above table, exit codes 1 - 2, 126 - 165, and 255
>   have special meanings, and should therefore be avoided for
>   user-specified exit parameters. Ending a script with exit 127 would
>   certainly cause confusion when troubleshooting (is the error code a
>   "command not found" or a user-defined one?). However, many scripts use
>   an exit 1 as a general bailout-upon-error. Since exit code 1 signifies
>   so many possible errors, it is not particularly useful in debugging.
>
> There has been an attempt to systematize exit status numbers (see
>   /usr/include/sysexits.h), but this is intended for C and C++
>   programmers. A similar standard for scripting might be appropriate.
>   The author of this document proposes restricting user-defined exit
>   codes to the range 64 - 113 (in addition to 0, for success), to
>   conform with the C/C++ standard. This would allot 50 valid codes, and
>   make troubleshooting scripts more straightforward.
>
> Out of range exit values can result in unexpected exit codes. An exit
>   value greater than 255 returns an exit code modulo 256. For example,
>   exit 3809 gives an exit code of 225 (3809 % 256 = 225).