# What actually prints "Segmentation fault"?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

Which binary or piece of code is printing *Segmentation fault* on the console when an error occurs?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the shell. It gets notified that its child process exited with `SIGSEGV` and prints the message.

Comment: I am pretty shure that the shell gets exactly no information what was happened during execution of a subprocess. The only interface is the return value...

Comment: @Klaus: That's more or less right, but in the case of a segmentation fault, the return value will indicate that the process was terminated by a SIGSEGV signal - so the shell is able to (and does) print this message :)

Comment: Can you tell me which return value has the meaning of SIGSEGV?

Comment: @Klaus, `128 + <signal number>`. `SIGSEGV` is usually `11`, so `139`.

Comment: So if i write a main() which simply returns this value should result in printing the message? I believe this will not work.

Comment: @Klaus `man 2 waitpid`

Comment: @Klaus, that won't work indeed, because returning a status code from `main()` is (roughly) an implicit call to `exit()`, and `exit()` [causes *normal* process termination](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit). See [Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101957/464709) for more information.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: for ksh93 it apparently is `256 + <signal number>`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99134/1987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the invoking shell's job, when job control is enabled.  Demonstration with bash:

```
$ set +m                    # disable job control
$ bash -c 'kill -SEGV $$'
$ set -m                    # enable job control
$ bash -c 'kill -SEGV $$'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: In a more general form it's the parent job ? I've done a small binary that forks and the parent wait() returns 139 (segfault).

Comment: You're correct in your representation of it. :-) But careful with the words, in this context "job" is a specific term that applies to the child process. The parent *process*, which is a shell, is the one responsible for tracking its child processes, that it calls jobs (hence the phrase "job control"). It is that parent shell that notifies when they terminate abnormally, via a signal.

Comment: It's parent's duty. :-)