# How to catch call process error in python call with subprocess

Tags: python, debugging, subprocess

Trying to debug a program (with buffer overflows) with a script on python I need to recover all messages a program may send.

On Linux, on terminal a normal call as  **./a.out AAA**
respond with

> Your argument is: AAA

with a overflow input: **./a.out AAAAAAA**
respond with

> Your argument is: AAAAAAA
>
> Segmentation fault

I building the python code as follows

```
import sys, string, os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

processName = os.getcwd() + "/a.out"
argument = "AAAAAAAAA"

p = Popen([processName, argument], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = p.communicate()
print(":: %d %s %s" % (p.returncode, output, error))
```

but I am unable to get the **Segmentation fault** message

neither found needed parameter as far as I have search

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250893/capture-segmentation-fault-message-for-a-crashed-subprocess-no-out-and-err-af

Answer (score 0):

The process does not actually print `Segmentation fault`. When you run `a.out` from the shell, this is actually produced by the shell itself. So, it is not a message produced by your program.

See [What actually prints "Segmentation fault"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564735/what-actually-prints-segmentation-fault)

But, you can check the return code of your process to see if it was stopped by a segmentation fault by comparing `p.returncode` to `-signal.SIGSEGV` from the `signal` module, see the question linked to below for details.

This question is a possible duplicate of [Capture "Segmentation fault" message for a crashed subprocess: no out and err after a call to communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250893/capture-segmentation-fault-message-for-a-crashed-subprocess-no-out-and-err-af)