# The exit status in Linux shell

Tags: linux, unix

why the exit status in Linux/shell i.e in $? is **128 plus the status number**.  I have searched but couldn't find proper explanation.

Comment: It's usually 128 + the signal number.

Answer (score 1):

If the exit status is > 127, it's usually the signal number plus 128. The reason is the signal occupies the highest bit in the binary representation of the status.

E.g. 130:

```
10000010
^     ^
|     |
|     2, i.e. SIGINT
killed by a signal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the excerpt from `bash(1)`:

```
The return value of a simple command is its exit status, or 128+n if the command is terminated by signal n.
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value in POSIX compatible systems is only 1 byte = 8 bits = 255 possible values. Unless you find an odd system that supports more than that, you should pick a different set of values.

You can take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux) for more details on returned standards code.