# How to include a Typescript type check step into a `build.sh` script file?

Tags: typescript, build, sh, typechecking, tsc

I'd like to incorporate a type check in my build process.

I keep my build process in a `build.sh` file where a call multiple CLI like:

```
// TYPE CHECK HERE <---
rimraf dist
webpack...
babel...
```

I'd like to type check my `/src` folder and stop my build process if it find any type errors.

How can I do that? Should I use `tsc`? Is there any option I need to add to make it stop in case it finds any errors?

I'm trying implement this basic functionality example:

**test.sh**

```
tsc src/testScript.ts --noEmit --skipLibCheck
echo "AFTER TSC"
```

I've intentionally added this error to the `testScript.ts`.

[image]

You can see that the rest of the `test.sh` script just keeps running. Is there a way to check if the `tsc` call has found any errors? Then I could check the result and stop the script at that point.

Comment: Yes, You should use `tsc`. See docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html. `tsc src/*.ts`

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks. It works as far as running the type check. But it does not stop the script from keep running after `tsc` has found errors. How could I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I've implemented this:

**build.sh**

```
TYPE_ERRORS="$(tsc --project ./tsconfig.json)"

if [[ -n $TYPE_ERRORS ]]; then
  echo "FOUND ERRORS"
  echo $TYPE_ERRORS
  echo "WILL EXIT NOW"
  exit
fi

echo "NO ERRORS WERE FOUND"
```

The result of the `tsc` will be stored in `$TYPE_ERRORS`. If the result is not empty, it will log the errors and exit the script. Else, the script will continue and log `NO ERRORS WERE FOUND`.

**Note:** Instead of logging the errors by doing `echo $TYPE_ERRORS`, you can also call the `tsc` command again, because the log will be prettier (with colors). Like:

**build.sh**

```
TYPE_ERRORS="$(tsc --project ./tsconfig.json)"

if [[ -n $TYPE_ERRORS ]]; then
  echo "FOUND ERRORS"
  tsc --project ./tsconfig.json   # THIS WILL LOG PRETTIER LOGS
  echo "WILL EXIT NOW"
  exit
fi

echo "NO ERRORS WERE FOUND"
```

The log from `echo $TYPE_ERRORS` will be plain text only (no colors).

---

The code above will look in `tsconfig.json` to see which compiler options should be applied and also which folders must by compiled.

But you can also specify folder/file, like:

```
tsc src/someFile.ts --noEmit --someOtherOption
```

---

This is how I call the `.sh` file from an npm script:

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build: "./my-bash-scripts-folder/build.sh"
  }
}
```

Than I run it as `npm run build` like always.

---

**UPDATE: USING EXIT CODES**

You can use the [exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux#:%7E:text=Programs%20return%20a%2016%20bit%20exit%20code.&text=Bash%20keeps%20the%20lower%207,to%20return%20errno%20on%20error.) from the `tsc` script to know if it has thrown any errors.

The standard is `0` for successful runs.

```
tsc --project ./tsconfig.json
TYPE_CHECK_EXIT_CODE=$?

if [[ $TYPE_CHECK_EXIT_CODE == "0" ]]; then
  echo "TYPE CHECK - SUCCESS"
else
  echo "TYPE CHECK - FAILED"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I've started using `.sh` script files, I've been able to do so much more custom stuff in my test, build, start and deploy scripts. Instead of relying solely on npm scripts.

Comment: After your answer, I wil reconsider my aproach to npm scripts. Could You please recommend some resource to learn more about bash scripts?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I google around a lot. But I think I've read parts of this [tutorial on TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/shell_scripting.htm) and also this [bash cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/bash) has helped me a lot.