# With powershell a Gitlab-ci job passed while failure occured

Tags: powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My gitlab-ci.yml contains follwing Lint code

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - exit 1
```

When running, the job doesn't fail!

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.10.0 (54944146)
Preparing the "shell" executor
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository
Checking out b70613dd
git-lfs/2.13.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.13; git fc664697)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:03
$ exit 1
Cleaning up file based variables
00:03
Job succeeded
```

How to avoid having false successes while the job should fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tests in Gitab CI pipeline marked as passed when 2 tests cases fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69574208/tests-in-gitab-ci-pipeline-marked-as-passed-when-2-tests-cases-fail)

Comment: I have found a solution. The issue is in the powershell shell. When using powershell-core, the problem does no longer appear. I do not understand yet why powershell-5 (windows default) returns a false result.

Comment: Glad you solved it! I’ll withdraw my vote since it’s a slightly different issue than it seemed. By the way, you can post an answer to your own question so others know this particular issue has an answer if you’re interested.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell 5 (the Windows default PS instance) returns a false result. When using PowerShell Core, the problem no longer appears.