# Where do I find exit status codes and their meanings?

Tags: go, exit-code

I was watching a tutorial on concurrency in golang and after hitting a race condition the program exited with status code 66.

- What does 66 actually mean?
- Where does this come from?  (If there's no standardization, how can I find the source file that defines this?)

I understand you can set the status code with the Exit pkg:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/carlmjohnson/exitcode#Exit

I found this resource for Linux, but it's missing 3-125
https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: For linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux should answer your question.

Comment: There are few *consistent* uses for anything above 2 and below the <sysexits.h> values.

Answer (score 1):

The exit code doesn't have a generic meaning -- not a meaning shared with the exit code of all linux programs.

The doc page for the [race detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector#Options) indicates that the `66` exit code is just a value the go developpers chose -- it is "non standard" enough to indicate that the cause was a race detection -- and that you can actually change it via the `GORACE` environment variable :

```
$ GORACE="exitcode=42" go run -race my_racey_program.go
...
exit status 42
```

---

As far as source code goes : the go repository contains a bunch of `*.syso` binary files under [`src/runtime/race/`](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/go1.18.4/src/runtime/race) (<- link to go1.18.4 posted),

and the comment at the beginning of [`src/runtime/race/race.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.18.4/src/runtime/race/race.go) mentions :

> ...
> The prebuilt race runtime lives in race_GOOS_GOARCH.syso.
> Calls to the runtime are done directly from src/runtime/race.go.