# How does the exit code of “test” act as a “if” condition?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I’m getting confused with using the test command inside a script. Normally I am experienced with Linux but lately I was not able to get my head around the following problem:

I want to check if a directory exists by using `test -d dir`. Depending if the directory exists or not I want to return a `echo` output. So the `if` statement will look somewhat like this:

```bash
if test -d $HOME/dir
then
    echo $?
    echo The directory exists.
else
    echo $?
    echo The directory does not exist.
fi
```

My problem now is understanding the error codes. Why does the `if` statement go into the condition `True` block when the error code of the `test` command is 0?
From my understanding it should be the other way around, especially if I don’t specify a condition but simply use `if test …`.

I have read the man file of `test` but I wasn’t getting any smarter. In addition I tested to use a condition for the `if` statement like this:

```bash
test -d $HOME/dir
exitcode=$(echo $?)

if [ "$exitcode" -ne 0 ]
then
    echo -e exit is $exitcode
    echo -e does not exist
else
    echo -e exit is $exitcode
    echo -e exists
fi
exit
```

Of course both scripts return the same output, but again: I don’t know why using the `test` command together with the `if` statement makes the `if` statement go inside the condition `true` block when the exit code is 0.

Comment: I recommend avoiding `echo -e` (or any other `-option` to `echo`). Some versions of `echo` will print the "-e" as part of their output, making it somewhat unsafe (I once had all my scripts that used it break when an OS update included bash compiled with different options, and `echo` started behaving differently...). If you actually wanted escape sequences interpreted in the string (you don't, but that's what `-e` tells `echo` to do), it's much better to [use `printf` with an appropriate format string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking about this slightly backwards. `if` doesn't test Boolean expressions. (The shell itself doesn't have Boolean expressions *to* test.) `if` always executes a command and checks for a zero-vs-non-zero exit status.

`[` itself is just a synonym for `test`, and `test` is a command that basically uses a mini-language to construct a Boolean expression from its arguments, evaluates that expression, then exits 0 if the expression is true, and 1 if it is false.

The convention is opposite that used by C and C-like languages, where 1 is true and 0 is false. Because a command typically can succeed in one way, but fail in may *different* ways, we use the unique non-positive value 0 to indicate success, but different positive values to indicate failure. It is a further convention that 1 itself represents a general error, but many commands use different non-zero exit status to indicate different errors. Sometimes, you care about a distinction between 1 and 2, other times you don't. When you do, you can use a `case` statement to distinguish them. For example,

```
grep "$some_regex" foo.txt

case $? in
  0) echo "regex matched"
  1) echo "regex did not match"
  *) echo "some error running grep, we don't know if the regex matches or not"
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Because exit code `0` means *success*, and any other exit code means error.

Try it:

```
true && echo "true=$?";   # true=0
false && echo "false=$?"; # false=1
```

Useful resources:

- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/exit.html
- [Are there any standard exit status codes in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

An exit code of zero means "no error", so that various errors can each have distinct nonzero returns, which you can use for debugging (or whatever else your creative little heart manages.)

`&&` and `||` use the same method, as does `while` and every other conditional evaluation.

Think of it this way: if you give a bogus argument, a specific error code can point that out; if a file you gave has no permissions, a different code can point to that.

```
$: cat foo
#!/usr/bin/bash
if ( exit $((RANDOM%3)) )
then echo RANDOM was evenly divisible by three
else case $? in
     2) echo "This simulates (for example) a bad input"   ;;
     1) echo "This simulates (for example) a failed read" ;;
     esac
fi
```

Now by checking the error code on fails, we can determine *which* problem we had.

```
$: for x in 1 2 3 4 5; do ./foo; done
This simulates (for example) a failed read
This simulates (for example) a bad input
RANDOM was evenly divisible by three
This simulates (for example) a bad input
RANDOM was evenly divisible by three
```

So for the five executions above, we know the first returned a 1, the second and fourth returned 2, and the third and fifth returned zero.