# Why does 'fopen' return a NULL pointer?

Tags: c, null, fopen, fwrite

I'm working on a simple file splitter/merger program in the C programming language. The problem is, for some reason [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) returns NULL, and because of that, my program is crashing at the [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) statement. How do I fix this?

Here is the C file:

```
int SplitFile(char* filename, char* output, size_t size)
{
    char current_file_name[256];
    int file_count = 0, i = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    printf("split %s into chunks of %d named\n", filename, size);

    if (!file)
       return E_BAD_SOURCE;
    else
    {
        output = (char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        if (output == NULL)
            return E_NO_MEMORY;
        else
        {
            int bytes_read = 0;
            FILE *outFile;
            do
            {
                bytes_read = fread(output, sizeof(char), size, file );
                sprintf(current_file_name, "%s%04lu\n", "part", file_count++);
                outFile = fopen (current_file_name, "wb" );  // THIS RETURNS NULL
                fwrite(output, sizeof(char), bytes_read, outFile); //CRASHES ON THIS LINE
            }
            while ( bytes_read > 0 )
                ;

            //fclose(outFile);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Snarky - check the file opened before you try to write to it. The real answer is you probably don't have the file system permissions or it is in a folder path that doesn't exist

Comment: What error is stored into `errno`? Just add `if (!outFile)perror("fopen");` and let the library tell you why it failed. :)

Comment: in errno I'm getting fopen : Invalid Argument

Comment: Are you giving the right path?

Comment: it should use the default path( the folder which contains the .c and .h ). I don't thing it's related to path

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The proper thing to do is check [`errno`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means) when `fopen` returns `NULL`.

I'm going to guess that your problem is that you're trying to write to a filesystem that doesn't allow `\n` in filenames, but it could be a permissions issue as well.

Comment: The more proper thing to do is check errno when fopen returns NULL.  You probably meant fopen instead of fwrite.

Comment: when I comment out the sprintf and do this; outFile =  fopen ( "part000" , "wb" ); it works fine.

Comment: @user: Have you taken the `\n` out of your `sprintf` line, then?

Comment: yeah it worked when I took out the \n. Thanks a lot. But I don't understand why \n causing the fopen to return NULL.

Comment: @user: The `\n` character is not allowed in a filename. That causes `fopen` to fail, so it returns NULL.

Comment: it would help to see an example of checking `errno`. that's why we're here, to learn :)

Comment: @jenkizenki there's an example in this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753143/10564382)

Answer (score 13):

There are many reasons `fopen` can return `NULL` including (but certainly not limited to):

- The file doesn't exist
- The file is opened in a mode that doesn't allow other accesses
- The network is down
- The file exists, but you don't have permissions
- A file exists with the name you gave, but the current directory of the process is not what you expected so the relative pathname fails to find and open the file.

The way to find out which is responsible is to dig into the `errno` code.

However just because you resolve this particular error doesn't mean you can assume `fopen` will never return `NULL`. When dealing with I/O operations your code simply has to expect failure. It's not possible to predict the success of I/O operations, and they can always fail.

Comment: what about running out of space? wouldn't that make it return NULL?
(i know you said "not limited to" my question is not rhetoric)

Comment: @Nande: `fopen()` that creates a new file may or may not succeed on a full disk.  If the directory doesn't need expanding (and you're not out of inodes), it can succeed, but a following `fwrite()` (**or** `fclose()`!) will fail.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the file might not exist or some permission error occurred while accessing a file such as "Read-Only" or "Write-Protected", so in those cases fopen will return 0 (a NULL pointer). On success it will return a file pointer as a handler.

`fp=fopen("c:\\ABC.txt", "r");` cannot be the same as `fp=fopen("c:\\abc.txt", "r");`.

Use `//` instead of `\\` in a Linux environment.

**P.S.:** In Linux and Unix-like operating systems file names are *case-sensitive*.

Answer (score 0):

Is fopen for write return NULL in the first run?

I noticed that in the while you keep open files for write but not closing them.

Try to add fclose(outFile) after fwrite:

```
outFile =  fopen ( current_file_name , "wb" );    
fwrite(output, sizeof( char ), bytes_read, outFile); 
fclose(outFile)
```

It is possible you open more files than your OS allows.

Comment: yeah I thought the same thing and closed the files, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, for fopen(), there is no reason to prepend ./ to a filename passed to fopen().

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was reading the same file all over again in a while loop and forgot to close it.

I used a function for reading the file and finding a match and the function had a `return;` statement that terminated the function before doing `fclose(fp)` :D

Answer (score 0):

The path given for the file is checked from wherever the executable is present.
In my case I was opening the text file in c file when both were present at the same place. 
It was continuously giving the error of file not found.
Placed the file in the folder of executable and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was trying to create the file in a **directory that does NOT exist**.