# C fopen fails for write with errno is 2

Tags: c, fopen, errno

I do not understand why this is seemingly failing with errno of 2:

```
char debugText [256];
sprintf (debugText, "C:\\List.txt");
dfile = fopen( debugText, "w");
fprintf ( dfile, "  err %d \n", errno);
```

I say seemingly because while dfile is NULL the file gets created and is filled with my output.

so what is going on ?

Comment: What type is `dfile`? Where's the test for `NULL`?

Comment: take a look at `strerror()` which return a string that explains `errno` for you.

Comment: (For the googlers)For me it was that the file had no write permissions. On Windows: Right click > Properties > Security > Edit. Then allow modify for all users

Comment: @SergioBasurco Perhaps it is a better fix, to make the file point to a location where regular users are allowed to write. Not everyone has administrator access at their pc and those rights should not be used to correct programming errors.

Answer (score 15):

All this tells you is that `errno` had the value 2 after your `fopen` call. You don't know that the call failed, because you didn't check whether `dfile == NULL`. If the output was actually written to the file, presumably the `fopen` call succeeded and the `errno` value was left over from some previous call, likely one you didn't make explicitly.

It's entirely possible for a successful call to `fopen` to set `errno` to a non-zero value.

Failing calls can set `errno` to some non-zero value, but successful calls *don't* set `errno` to 0. To check for errors, you need to

- Set `errno` to 0 before the call;
- Make the call and check the value it returned to see whether it succeeded or failed; and
- Check the value of `errno` after the call -- but *only* if you know it failed (otherwise the value of `errno` is meaningless).

If `dfile == NULL`, then the `fprintf` call has undefined behavior; it will probably fail.

On the other hand, you say that `dfile` is `NULL`. How do you know that? Your code doesn't check it. (If the `fopen` call really did fail, could the contents of `C:\List.txt` be left over from a previous run of your program?)

What output do you get from this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(void) {
    char debugText [256];
    FILE *dfile;

    sprintf (debugText, "C:\\List.txt");
    dfile = fopen( debugText, "w");
    if (dfile == NULL) {
        printf("fopen failed, errno = %d\n", errno);
    }
    else {
        printf("fopen succeeded\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see dfile is NULL 'cause i am stepping through in debug mode. that is when i started grabbing errno.

Comment: You need to check whether `defile == NULL` *in your program*, and then not try to write to the file if it is. To verify why `fopen()` fails, do as I suggested with `errno`.  Assuming you're on a Windows system, opening `"C:\\List.txt"` for output shouldn't fail with `errno==2`, which means "No such file or directory". (You *are* on Windows, right? And not under Cygwin?)

Comment: @JPM: Try the program I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
2 ENOENT No such file or directory.  A component of a specified pathname
         did not exist, or the pathname was an empty string.
```

Here is a list of the error codes:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-error-codes/

But you should check if `fopen()` returned `NULL` first because this value in `errno` might be left over from something else.

Answer (score 5):

No library function ever sets `errno` to zero.

You should only check `errno` after a function reports an error.

For example, your code should be:

```
if ((dfile = fopen(debugText, "w")) == 0)
    ...then fopen() failed and errno is relevant...
```

If the function does not report failure, the value in `errno` may be anything.  For example, on Solaris, you often end up with `errno` set to `ENOTTY` after a successful operation, because `stdout` is not connected to a terminal.  It doesn't mean anything actually went wrong; it just means that a test for whether standard output is a terminal failed (because it isn't a terminal).

Comment: if file did exist fopen is supposed to delete and then create a new. clearly the path is not empty nor is the path non-existant:  C:\   so what i dont get is why dfile is NULL.  unless THAT is an aberratioin of VS2010 ?

Comment: You don't prove that `dfile == NULL`; indeed, since the following `fprintf()` uses it, it is improbable that `dfile` is null (you'd probably get a crash in `fprintf()` if it was null).  You'd have to revise your code to explicitly test `dfile` before I'd be willing to believe your assertion that `dfile` is null (and report the error on a channel other than `dfile`).

Answer (score 3):

Only write filename:
like below example works fine for me:
It will create file and write number entered by user in it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
void main() {
    int num;
   FILE *fptr;
   clrscr();
   fptr = fopen("num.txt","w");

   if(fptr == NULL)
   {
     fprintf(stderr,"open error for %s,errno = %d: %s\n",fptr, errno, strerror(errno));
     printf("Error!");
     exit(1);
   }

   printf("Enter num: ");
   scanf("%d",&num);

   fprintf(fptr,"%d",num);
   fclose(fptr);

   getch();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got `errno == 2` while trying to open file for writing on mounted flash drive with FAT file system; it turns out that if file doesn't comply with [8.3 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename), `fopen` returns `NULL` and sets `errno` to `ENOENT`.

It's necessary to say though, that I came across this situation on embedded system, and it shouldn't be the issue on Windows.

Comment: Yep, my bad. Edited my answer.