# fclose() causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, fopen, fclose

I've been trying simple file handling in C and I wanted to make sure that the file can be accessed tried using this

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    CheckFile();
}

int CheckFile()
{
    int checkfile=0;

    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("users.sav","r");

    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
        fopen("users.sav","w");
        fclose(fp1);
    }   
    if(checkfile!=0)printf("\nERROR ACCESSING FILE!\nNow exiting program with exit code: %d\n",checkfile);exit(1);
    return 0;
}
```

then it displays

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but it doesn't segfault if the file already exists beforehand (e.g. when i created it manually or when i run the program the second time)

Please help. I need this for our final project due in a week and I haven't gotten the hang of files and pointers yet.

I'm using "gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1"

P.s

I saw this in another question

> There's no guarantee in your original code that the fopen is actually working, in which case it will return NULL and the fclose will not be defined behaviour.

So how exactly do I check if it worked?

Comment: The check is correct, just don't `fclose(fp1)` if `fp1 == NULL` but call `fp1 = fopen(..., "w");`

Comment: Thanks :)

The answers really helped me out coding has been going smoothly so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fclose() causing segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443164/fclose-causing-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 8):

That's normal, when you call `fclose(fp1)` when fp1 is NULL.

BTW

```
fopen("users.sav","w");
```

is useless because you don't assign the return value to a file pointer. That means the users.sav file will be opened for writing, but you will never be able to write anything in it .

Answer (score 4):

`fopen` returns a `FILE` pointer. It will return `NULL` and set the global `errno` to indicate the error. If you want to check the `errno`, you have to check if after you check if `fopen` returned `NULL`.

```
if (fp1 == NULL)
{
    printf("fopen failed, errno = %d\n", errno);
}
```

Otherwise, you may get an `errno` from something else, not necessarily your `fopen` call. Also include `errno.h`. You also don't need to call `fopen("users.sav","w");` again. You aren't reassigning the pointer nor checking it again.

I don't see a reason to call `fclose` here since if `fopen` returns `NULL`, there isn't anything to close. That is probably the reason for your seg fault. You are trying to close a null pointer. [More information on fopen failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753090/c-fopen-fails-for-write-with-errno-is-2).

Another comment on your code. If you are going to return an `int` from `CheckFile`, it should probably not be `0` on fail. I would return `-1` to indicate an error. Better yet, you could return the global `errno`. Also, `main` should be `int main()` and you should `return 0;` at the end. I don't particularly care for your naming scheme of `CheckFile`. In C, `check_file` or camelCase of `checkFile` would be better.

In `CheckFile`, your one line `if` statement could be formatted and work more properly if you formatted it on multiple lines. It doesn't do what you think it does currently:

```
if(checkfile!=0)
{
   printf("\nERROR ACCESSING FILE!\nNow exiting program with exit code: %d\n", checkfile);
   exit(1);
}
```

Also, `checkfile` is never set anywhere in your code.. other than zero. So the code in the `if` statement will not execute, period.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but the immediate problem is here:

```
if(fp1==NULL)
   fclose(fp1);
```

After asserting that fp1 is NULL, you're trying to call `close` on the null pointer, which will cause a segmentation fault.

If all you want to do is verify that the file exists, try something like [What's the best way to check if a file exists in C? (cross platform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform)

Answer (score 0):

The man page of `fclose` says -

> The behaviour of fclose() is undefined if the stream parameter is an
>   illegal pointer, or is a descriptor already passed to a previous
>   invocation of fclose().

The error is in the `if` block in your code.

```
if(fp1==NULL)
{
    fopen("users.sav","w");
    fclose(fp1);  // passing NULL to fclose invokes undefined behaviour
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another unrelated problem:

This line is probably not what you want:

```
if(checkfile!=0)printf("\nERROR ACCESSING FILE!\nNow exiting program with exit code: %d\n",checkfile);exit(1);
```

If we write it correctly formatted the error becomes obvious:

```
if (checkfile != 0)
  printf("\nERROR ACCESSING FILE!\nNow exiting program with exit code: %d\n",checkfile);

exit(1);
return 0 ;
```

Actually we will get to `exit(1)` even if `checkfile` is zero.

You probably want this:

```
if (checkfile != 0)
{
  printf("\nERROR ACCESSING FILE!\nNow exiting program with exit code: %d\n",checkfile);
  exit(1); 
}

return 0 ;
```

Conclusion: format your code correctly and many errors will suddenly look obvious.

Comment: You should probably roll this into your other answer, good catch :)

Comment: @GIJoe: Well, I was not sure if I should have done this because this issue it's totally unrelated to the original question.

Comment: I would.. makes your answer stronger.

Comment: It definitely did... It also pointed out a whole lot of other complications in my code that I didn't notice (hence it was not included in my question) but would probably haunt me as well... I guess this **final project** thing is just really getting on my nerves.