# SIGSEGV after running a Python script for 2nd time

Tags: python-3.x, qt, segmentation-fault

I want to plot some data using matplotlib and a python script if a button in a Qt application is pressed. The slot which receives the signal from the startPythonButton is defined in the following way:

```
void MainWindow::on_wdgt_startPython_clicked()
{
    FILE* file;
    Py_Initialize();
    file=fopen("/home/user/test.py","r");
    if(file<0){
        Py_Finalize();
        return;
    }
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file,"/home/user/test.py");
    Py_Finalize();
    fclose(file);
}
```

The python script is defined as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y=np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

When I run the Qt program and click the startPythonButton, the plot is shown normally. When I close the plot-window and click the startPythonButton again however, the Qt process receives a SIGSEGV when trying to call `PyRun_SimpleFile`.

Any ideas where the error could be?

---

So it turns out that the second fopen() call does not fail (e.g. does not return NULL):

```
void MainWindow::on_wdgt_startPython_clicked()
{
    FILE* file;
    Py_Initialize();
    file=fopen("/home/user/test.py","r");
    if(file==NULL){
        std::stderr << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
        Py_Finalize();
        return;
    }
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file,"/home/user/test.py");
    Py_Finalize();
    if(fclose(file)!=0){
        std::stderr << "Failed to close file." << std::endl;
        return;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) is not used correctly.  It returns `NULL` on failure.  You need to replace the test `if(file<0)` with `if(file==NULL)`. As it stands, you are missing the failure case.

It is advisable to provide user feedback if such an operation fails.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987626/why-does-fopen-return-a-null-pointer) (probably among many others) shows how to fetch more details about `fopen` errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it seems like neither the fopen() or the fclose() call fail. I checked this in the debugger. The second fopen() call seems to return a faulty filepointer which causes the SIGSEGV. I added the new code to the original post.