# Why does my C++ program crash with exit code 11 when I remove a cout statement?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cout

In my C++ project, I encounter a very strange issue. It crashes with *exit code 11* when I *remove* a certain log statement (`cout`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038586/return-code-from-pthread-create-is-11) points to a source that explains exit code 11 (actually `EAGAIN`) with the following statement:

> The system lacked the necessary resources to create another thread, or
>   the system-imposed limit on the total number of threads in a process
>   PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX would be exceeded.

But I am pretty sure don't create any additional threads in my code (at least not explicitly). So why does the error occur and why does it go away when I use the log statement?

For reference, I will post the code but it's of course completely out of context and basically the only relevant line is the one with the log statement.

```
 PayloadRegionMapper(string mappingTechniqueName, string configPath = "")
    : payload(PAYLOAD), config(Config(configPath)) {

    cout << "construct PayloadRegionMapper" << endl; // if commented out, my program crashes....

    frames = generateFrames();
    setMappingTechnique(mappingTechniqueName);
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you attach a debugger?

Comment: run a memory checker, like valgrind

Comment: Did you try replacing the `cout` with another statement? And is that a `std::cout`?

Comment: Is this code snipped run in a concurring thread? It seems like a race condition.

Comment: Sounds like there is some UB in your code

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes it's `std::out`... and I just replaced the statement and used another (random) one (`int a = 4`)... that indeed also prevents a crash...

Comment: most likely you have Undefined Behavior in your code, and the compiler behaves differently depending on whether that statement exists or not. The cout is not the problem.

Comment: @nburk That's very odd. From just the snippet, I have no clue, but it's also only a fairly narrow window into your program.

Comment: hmm.. yeah I don't think posting any more code will help much. I'm quite a novice to C++ so I guess I'll first go and do some reading on UB and maybe find strategies to resolve them (and reinspect my code for that matter...). thanks for the hints to everyone!

Comment: Try removing the cout, then taking your remaining two functions calls (generateFrames and setMappingTechnique) and commenting them out one at a time.

If the call to setMappingTechnique requires generateFrames to have done something, you may need to add a minimal amount of filler code to get it to run.

Generally you want to start trying to eliminate other things that are running one at a time and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Try to replace cout with a Sleep(100) and see if it still fails. If not, then you are most likely has a concurrency issue, otherwise I would guess it is a memory allocation/access problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program using a debugger and then backtrace once the crash happens.
Using the bt and frame command you can get an idea about the behaviour of the program during the crashing situation.

```
gdb <executable>

.....<crash happened>

bt
<It will give you the stack frame >

frame <frame number>

Then look for the values and memory area there.
```