# Why does mmap defined in a Linux kernel module return MAP_FAILED?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to map a kernel buffer in user space using mmap method in linux 3.10.10. But it is returning `MAP_FAILED`. Why it is failed to map the buffer.

Kernel module

```
#include <linux/module.h>  /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>  /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <sound/core.h>
#include <sound/initval.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/io.h>
//#include <linux/malloc.h>

#include <linux/mm.h>  /* mmap related stuff */

long long  *buf1;
long long* buf;


static int driver_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
  vma->vm_flags |= VM_LOCKED|VM_SHARED;

  int i = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
             virt_to_phys(buf) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
             vma->vm_end-vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot);

  SetPageReserved(virt_to_page(buf));
  printk("MMAP \n");
  return 0;
}


struct file_operations proc_fops =
{
  mmap:driver_mmap,
};
int init_module_test(void)
{
  int i;
  buf1 = kmalloc(4096, __GFP_COLD|GFP_DMA);

  buf = ((int)buf1 + PAGE_SIZE -1) & PAGE_MASK;
  printk("<1>Hello world1\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
  {
    buf[i] = (long long) i + 1;
  }
  proc_create ("mmap_example",0,NULL, &proc_fops);
  printk("<1>Hello world3\n");
  printk("<1>BUF1 = 0x%08x\n BUF = 0x%08x\n", buf1,buf);
  return 0;
}


void cleanup_module_test(void)
{
  remove_proc_entry ("mmap_example", NULL);
  kfree(buf1);
  printk("Goodbye world\n");
}



module_init(init_module_test);
module_exit(cleanup_module_test);
```

Application code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fd, i;
  long long *msg = NULL;

  if ((fd = fopen("/proc/mmap_example", "r")) < 0)
  {
    printf("File not opened");
  }
  msg = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (msg == MAP_FAILED)
  {
    printf("MAP failed");
    return 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    printf("0x%llx,", msg[i]);

  fclose(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

I always end up seing `"MAP failed"`.
Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: should not be `mmap:driver_mmap,` in the struct initialization `.mmap = driver_mmap`?

Comment: I think doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @mch, you proposed legacy way to initialize structure fields. On modern C we use the pattern `.field = value,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you are attempting to use `fopen` to open a file and placing the return value in an integer, but `fopen` doesn't return an integer. It returns `FILE *`. This tells me you are ignoring compiler warnings and errors. That's a bad idea: they're produced for a reason.

The second problem is that you actually do need an integer file handle in order to provide it as an argument to `mmap(2)`. For that, you should be calling `open(2)` (*not* `fopen(3)`).

There may well be additional problems with this code, but that's a start.

Answer (score 1):

well, i can't comment so i post an answer that is not one, but i hope it will be still useful:

i'm not sure about the driver, but you can use the errno method (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) on mmap to have a better answer on why it's failing:

add in your application code at the right place:

```
#include <errno.h>
printf("%i",errno);
```

or you could maybe use the following if you don't want to print the errno :

```
cpp -dM /usr/include/errno.h | grep 'define E' | sort -n -k 3
```

from [How to know what the 'errno' means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means)

Comment: I am getting Bad file descriptor in errno

Comment: While you said this answer is not one, it exactly leads to answering the question :-)   Bad file descriptor ---> fopen didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**debugfs can't handle `mmap`**

I know this is not your exact case, but it also makes `mmap` fail with `MAP_FAILED`, and it may help future Googlers: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9252557/

And here is a [fully working procfs example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/8d668d6ed3617cc47425e1413513a2d1f99a25fd/kernel_module/user/mmap.c) with an [userland test](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/8d668d6ed3617cc47425e1413513a2d1f99a25fd/kernel_module/mmap.c).