# Can't open obb file although it is there

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

I'm trying to mount an obb file but

```
std::fstream test("/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.bixense.jngl_test/main.1.com.bixense.jngl_test.obb");
assert(test);
```

says it doesn't exist (or I can't access it). When looking via adb shell the file is located here:

```
/storage/sdcard1/Android/obb/com.bixense.jngl_test/main.1.com.bixense.jngl_test.obb
```

Do I need to give my app some special permission?

Comment: What is your target SDK version?

Comment: project.properties has target=android-20, so I guess 20? There's APP_PLATFORM := android-10 in my Application.mk file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've fixed it using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml. Strange, I thought I've read that this isn't needed for accessing my own files ...

Answer (score 2):

I would try to access it in good old C style and print `strerror(errno)` as in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/504039/755804

Comment: Thanks! This gives me "No such file or directory" though :(

Comment: Ah wait: It's "Permission denied". So I'll have to add some permission to my app, right?