# How can create directory dynamically in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a directory in [PL/pgsql](http://www.plsqltutorial.com/):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getNextId() RETURNS VARCHAR(200) AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
    mfId integer;
    rootDir varchar(50) := 'mfdata/';
    createDir text := 'mkdir --mode=777 -p mfdata';
    dir varchar(100);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO copy.history(time) values(now()) RETURNING id INTO mfId;
    EXECUTE('COPY (SELECT 1) TO PROGRAM ' || quote_literal('mkdir --mode=777 -p mfdata '));
    RETURN 'mfdata' || mfId;
END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but occur an error as follow:

[image]

Where is the problem? How can create directory dynamically in PL/pgSQL?

Comment: Works for me. Does that command work for you from shell, in main directory, as postgres user?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I run this function from a trigger function(When a record changed, it run)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39950673/5315974 `1   EPERM             Operation not permitted` - user that runs posrtgres cluster has no permissions on the parent(s) directory(ies), also why not using the full path?..

Comment: full path => same result. I changed parent folder permission to full access, but result is same