# AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -32

Tags: android, c, android-mediaplayer, soundpool, audioflinger

I've an apps playing short sound <5 seconds but sometimes the audio is not playing(no sound), the audio file is ogg with 128kbps bitrate and 44100hz sample rate, i've try searching google about this but didn't found the solution, here's the log when audio is not playing

```
2019-02-25 14:02:39.019  W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 44100 Hz, output 48000 Hz
2019-02-25 14:02:39.021 735-2284/? W/IAudioFlinger: CREATE_TRACK: cannot retrieve shared memory
2019-02-25 14:02:39.022  E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -32
2019-02-25 14:02:39.023  E/SoundPool: Error creating AudioTrack
```

what status -32 mean, anyone knows ?

edit: finally i know what error code 32 means from this [How to know what the 'errno' means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means)

but what might be causing error 32 (Broken Pipe) ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved it by now but i think you just need to make sure you close the sound pool to free up resources.

```
soundPool.release()
soundPool = null
```