# What are the possible side-effects of using gcc's -fno-math-errno?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm getting a massive speedup from using this option when compiling my code.  From the man page it says that this option:

> Do not set "errno" after calling math functions that are executed
>   with a single instruction, e.g., "sqrt"

Its not clear to me what the 'errno' is, and how it is used elsewhere (is this the same as the exit code of a program?) Furthermore, the man page says:

> A program that relies on IEEE exceptions for math error handling may
>   want to use this flag for speed while maintaining IEEE arithmetic
>   compatibility.

Its not clear to me what this means, are the IEEE exceptions standard for c++ or common libraries of c++ (e.g. Eigen, Boost, etc.)

Essentially, I'm trying to determine if this is a 'safe' option to use in my code, or what side-effects I should be aware of from its use. A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do/22135559#22135559) says this may affect 'thread local variables' but I have no clue what that means.

EDIT: My code is a simple one-off procedural code to handle a scientific problem. It is not going to be part of a deeply embeded system that requires complex error-handling. However, the code must not fail in subtle, silent ways.

Comment: Many standard math functions set `errno` on errors. Disabling that allows for simpler more optimized code paths, at the cost of making error detection harder.

Comment: @Shawn Looks like a decent answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know what the 'errno' means?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503878/608639)

Comment: With `-fno-math-errno` mathematical functions becomes equivalent to function declared with the `[[gnu::const]]` [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes). That improves drastically optimization.

Comment: @Oliv I don't see how those things are the same? `-fno-math-errno` is about the function's behaviour; `[[gnu::const]]` is about the behaviour's repeatability.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe you overestimate optimizer: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xx51O2).

Comment: @Oliv What I'm saying is that they fundamentally mean different things. Though without the `errno` setting it's probably easier for the optimiser to reach the same conclusion that you promise with `[[gnu::const]]`. That's not the same as saying it's "equivalent" though; not at all.

Comment: Caveat: there are also [undocumented side effects not only on math functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88576).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C introduced the concept of a single `errno` or "error number" that could be used to determine the precise cause of the failure of some standard functions, including mathematical functions, to perform their duties. POSIX extended `errno`, and C++11 picked up some of those extensions too.

When one of these functions fails, [the global integer `errno` is set to a value that tells you why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h). Obviously that incurs a performance penalty.

GCC is saying that this flag *disables* this behaviour for certain mathematical functions, speeding up your program at the cost of diagnostic utility and standard-compliance.

If you're already not observing `errno` when any of the affected functions fails, and you're probably not because you'd never heard of it, then you won't lose any functionality. This may be the case if you're writing a *really* time-constrained program, or when the particular reason for a failure doesn't dictate what your code does next. (However I advise looking into error checking more broadly to ensure that your code is as robust as it ought to be.)

---

However, it is possible for you to accidentally observe side-effects if you have a bug. Imagine if you were doing something like the following:

```
std::some_maths_function(42);
if (errno == ERANGE)
   exit(-1);
```

Oops! We are checking `errno` even when `some_maths_function(42)` succeeded. Let's say that above this code is a call to `std::some_other_maths_function(999)` which usually fails and results in `errno` being set to `EDOM`. That masked the bug in the code above.

Now turn on the compiler flag. If `some_other_maths_function` is one of the functions that no longer sets `errno`, your bug will be unmasked, and it may take you a few moments to realise that you ought to have written something more like:

```
if (std::some_maths_function(42) == -1)
{
   if (errno == RANGE)
      exit(-1);
}
```

Of course it's hardly GCC's fault that you had a bug, but this does show how the behaviour of your program can differ after enabling this "optimisation" flag. Indeed, [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) says:

> This option is not turned on by any -O option since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications.

In other words, this flag sends you off-book. But it may be worth it.

---

The variable `errno` must be thread-local (that is, there is actually one of them for each thread in your program) otherwise it'd be useless in a multi-threaded program. You can research the term "thread-local" for more information on this subject.

Comment: If I'm reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling correctly, as long as your libc plays nicely with the option by setting `math_errhandling` to the appropriate value (2), using it can still be compliant.

Comment: @Shawn Only if floating-point exceptions are used! I'm only guessing but I'd imagine this flag not to affect the value of `math_errhandling` and instead render the implementation non-compliant if its value has `MATH_ERRNO` masked into it.

Comment: @Shawn In fact the docs do say: _"This option is not turned on by any -O option since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications."_ In other words, this flag sends you off-book.

Comment: Unless you're on some funky hardware, you should hopefully have fp exceptions because they're required for IEEE floating point.

Comment: glibc, at least, looks like it defines `math_errhandling` correctly. The number of programs that check it before assuming that math functions set errno, now... That's probably a very small number. And pre C99/C++11 doesn't have that feature in the standards at all; it *would* break old code too.

Comment: @Shawn Not every maths operation that sets `errno` relates to floating-point. Although I admit I don't know how many of those are single-instruction. But, yes, you can rely on FP exceptions instead of `errno` if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that GCC might also disable errno for non-math functions such as `malloc` when -fno-math-errno is used. [0]

[0] [-fno-math-errno causes GCC to consider that malloc does not set errno](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88576)