# How to not link `impure_data` when call math.h?

Tags: c, embedded, riscv

I'm writing bare-metal microcontroller code and want to use simple math function from <math.h> like `sqrtf()`, but found `impure_data` in symbol list eats 0x428 bytes, from `lib_a-impure.o`.

It turns out that reentrant code is being linked in(according to [this](https://hackaday.com/2021/07/19/the-newlib-embedded-c-standard-library-and-how-to-use-it)), how to avoid this behavior?

I'm using `riscv64-unknown-elf` toolchain, seems like it does not have newlib-nano. What else can I do? Some complier flag maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550457/what-are-the-possible-side-effects-of-using-gccs-fno-math-errno).

Using `-fno-math-errno` can eliminate `impure_data`, and `sqrtf()` will become a single riscv instruction `fsqrt.s` instead of `__ieee754_sqrtf` subroutine.

Using `xpack-riscv-none-embed` toolchain (old GNU MCU Eclipse RISC-V Embedded GCC) with `-specs=nano.specs` will still have `impure_data`, but much smaller(0x428 -> 0x60 in my case, `sqrtf/__ieee754_sqrtf` are also smaller)