# Differentiate between return value and error in C

Tags: c, pointers, posix

I am trying to write a function that takes a linked list, an index and returns the value at the index+1 position.

```
int getData(list *l, int index) {
    if(...) { 
        ...
        return result; // this could be -1
    }

    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

In C you return a value of -1 when the function fails (as a way to let the user know that the call failed because of bad input). However, because the return type of this function is int, it includes the value of -1 (-1 as a number, as well ass -2, -3 etc)

My question is: Is there a mechanism in which you can return from your function and make the user of the function aware that the returned value is in fact an error and not a value?

Comment: C or C++? It seems like you mistakenly added a c++ tag to this question.

Comment: For C, look into `errno.h` -- see this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means

Comment: @gst `errno` is for system functions, not user functions.

Comment: @Barmar couldn't a user function set the value of `errno`? Would that be considered bad practice?

Comment: @gst It's allowed, just unusual. You have to be careful because it can be changed out from under you if you call other system functions.

Comment: I might be naive, but for me it seems that you need something like while (index++ < endIndex) currentNode = currentNode->next; return currentNode->value;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the value by passing a pointer and make the return value an error statement:

```
int getData(list *l, int inIndex, int* outIndex) {
    if(...) { 
        ...
        *outIndex = result;
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `*outIndex = result`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, made the mistake, because I am used to use pass-by-reference with `& ` which is only possible in C++